# How can I put an actual backslash in a string literal (not use it for an escape sequence)?

Tags: python, string, escaping, backslash, rawstring

I have this code:

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
final = path +'\xulrunner.exe ' + path + '\application.ini'
print(final)
```

I want output like:

```
C:\Users\me\xulrunner.exe C:\Users\me\application.ini
```

But instead I get an error that looks like:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape
```

I don't want the backslashes to be interpreted as escape sequences, but as literal backslashes. How can I do it?

---

<sub>Note that if the string should *only* contain a backslash - more generally, should have an *odd number of backslashes at the end* - then raw strings [**cannot** be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C148.0506). Please use [How can I get a string with a single backslash in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095796/) to close questions that are asking for a string with just a backslash in it. Use [How to write string literals in python without having to escape them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703516/) when the question is specifically about wanting to avoid the need for escape sequences.</sub>

Comment: See also [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python) if you are trying to make a string with a file path in it on Windows.

Comment: There is a reasonably good overview of escape sequences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31213916/523612), although that question isn't actually good quality - the underlying problem described by OP isn't actually anything to do with the escape sequences.

Comment: See also: [python: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561691/)

Comment: See also: [How to fix "<string> DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335970)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To answer your question directly, put `r` in front of the string.

```
final= path + r'\xulrunner.exe ' + path + r'\application.ini'
```

But a better solution would be `os.path.join`:

```
final = os.path.join(path, 'xulrunner.exe') + ' ' + \
         os.path.join(path, 'application.ini')
```

(the backslash there is escaping a newline, but you could put the whole thing on one line if you want)

I will mention that you can use forward slashes in file paths, and Python will automatically convert them to the correct separator (backslash on Windows) as necessary. So

```
final = path + '/xulrunner.exe ' + path + '/application.ini'
```

should work. But it's still preferable to use `os.path.join` because that makes it clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Python does not convert `/` into `\`, rather `/` is a valid path separator on Windows

Comment: Note that Windows can also be able to use forward slashes instead of backslashes in general; Python doesn't need to convert them.

Answer (score 35):

You can escape the slash. Use `\\` and you get just one slash.

Answer (score 5):

You can escape the backslash with another backslash (`\\`), but it won’t look nicer. To solve that, put an `r` in front of the string to signal a [*raw string*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640). A raw string will ignore **all** escape sequences, treating backslashes as literal text. It [cannot contain the closing quote unless it is preceded by a backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630465) (which will be included in the string), and it [cannot end with a single backslash (or odd number of backslashes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/).

Answer (score 0):

Another simple  (and arguably more readable) approach is using string raw format and replacements like so:

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
final = r"{0}\xulrunner.exe {0}\application.ini".format(path)
print(final)
```

or using the os path method (and a microfunction for readability):

```
import os

def add_cwd(path):
    return os.path.join( os.getcwd(), path )

xulrunner = add_cwd("xulrunner.exe")
inifile = add_cwd("application.ini")
# in production you would use xulrunner+" "+inifile
# but the purpose of this example is to show a version where you could use any character
# including backslash
final = r"{} {}".format( xulrunner, inifile )
print(final)
```