# python: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python, string, string-literals

I have the above-mentioned error in `s1="some very long string............"`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's being closed correctly and there aren't unescaped quotes somewhere?

Comment: Unescaped quotes throw another parsing error.

Comment: Note that since Python 3.10, the error message [will look a bit different](https://realpython.com/python310-new-features/#better-error-messages).

Comment: Does the actual string end with a backslash? Something as simple as `"\"` will cause that error.

Answer (score 288, accepted):

You are not putting a `"` before the end of the line.

Use `"""` if you want to do this:

```
""" a very long string ...... 
....that can span multiple lines
"""
```

Comment: And careful to only use three quotation marks, I had four by accident and the error came up

Answer (score 123):

I had this problem - I eventually worked out that the reason was that I'd included `\` characters in the string. If you have any of these, "escape" them with `\\` and it should work fine.

Comment: @Leo they are called 'escape characters', and this is pretty standard. You can put an `r` before the string to avoid them causing problems.

Comment: @eric you can do that if the \ is not at the very end of the string like `r'the cat in the hat\'`. I wish this wasn't the case, but it is

Comment: @scrollout good point I really wish they would fix that. It almost defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 19):

(Assuming you don't have/want line breaks in your string...)

How long is this string really?

I suspect there is a limit to how long a line read from a file or from the commandline can be, and because the end of the line gets choped off the parser sees something like `s1="some very long string..........` (without an ending `"`) and thus throws a parsing error?

You can split long lines up in multiple lines by escaping linebreaks in your source like this:

```
s1="some very long string.....\
...\
...."
```

Answer (score 13):

I faced a similar problem. I had a string which contained path to a folder in Windows e.g. `C:\Users\` The problem is that `\` is an escape character and so in order to use it in strings you need to add one more `\`.

Incorrect: `C:\Users\`

Correct:   `C:\\Users\\`

Comment: I have the same problem but this doesn't solve the issue. Putting additional 2 slashes makes first of them escape for the second one. And the last slash still causes problem.

Comment: @I.P. that appears to have been a typo in the post; it should be fixed now. However, see also [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/).

Answer (score 12):

In my situation, I had `\r\n` in my single-quoted dictionary strings. I replaced all instances of `\r` with `\\r` and `\n` with `\\n` and it fixed my issue, properly returning escaped line breaks in the eval'ed dict.

```
ast.literal_eval(my_str.replace('\r','\\r').replace('\n','\\n'))
  .....
```

Comment: I passed over this answer at first because it focused on the \r\n. The real issue here is `ast.literal_eval` which raises this error whenever it doesn't get a valid python literal. In my case I broke it with something like `ast.literal_eval('{"my": "dict"}"}')`.

Answer (score 9):

You can try this:

```
s = r'long\annoying\path'
```

Comment: That is the best answer. Can also try `s = r'long\annoying\path\\'`.

Answer (score 5):

I too had this problem, though there were answers here I want to an important point to this
after 
`/` there should not be empty spaces.Be Aware of it

Answer (score 4):

I also had this exact error message, for me the problem was fixed by adding an " \"

It turns out that my long string, broken into about eight lines with " \" at the very end, was missing a " \" on one line.

Python IDLE didn't specify a line number that this error was on, but it red-highlighted a totally correct variable assignment statement, throwing me off.  The actual misshapen string statement (multiple lines long with " \") was adjacent to the statement being highlighted.  Maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I use Windows so I have to use double quotes instead of single.

```
C:\Users\Dr. Printer>python -mtimeit -s"a = 0"
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.011 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case with Mac OS X, I had the following statement:

```
model.export_srcpkg(platform, toolchain, 'mymodel_pkg.zip', 'mymodel.dylib’)
```

I was getting the error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
model.export_srcpkg(platform, toolchain, 'mymodel_pkg.zip', 'mymodel.dylib’)
                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

After I change to:

```
model.export_srcpkg(platform, toolchain, "mymodel_pkg.zip", "mymodel.dylib")
```

It worked...

David

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I forgot **(' or ")** at the end of string. **E.g 'ABC'** or **"ABC"**

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error in postgresql function. I had a long SQL which I broke into multiple lines with \ for better readability. However, that was the problem. I removed all and made them in one line to fix the issue. I was using pgadmin III.

Answer (score 2):

Your `variable(s1)` spans multiple lines. In order to do this (i.e you want your string to span multiple lines), you have to use triple quotes(""").

```
s1="""some very long 
string............"""
```

Answer (score 2):

*All code below was tested with Python 3.8.3*

---

Simplest -- just use triple quotes.

Either single:

```
long_string = '''some
very 
long
string
............'''
```

or double:

```
long_string = """some
very 
long
string
............"""
```

**Note:** triple quoted strings retain indentation, it means that

```
long_string = """some
    very 
    long
string
............"""
```

and

```
long_string = """some
    very 
long
string
............"""
```

or even just

```
long_string = """
some
very 
long
string
............"""
```

**are not the same**.

There is a [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) function in standard library to deal with this, though working with it is out of question's scope.

---

You can, as well, use `\n` inside a string, residing on single line:

```
long_string = "some \nvery \nlong \nstring \n............"
```

---

Also, if you don't need any linefeeds (i.e. newlines) in your string, you can use `\` inside regular string:

```
long_string = "some \
very \
long \
string \
............"
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, three single quotations or three double quotations both will work!
For example:

```
    """Parameters:
    ...Type something.....
    .....finishing statement"""
```

OR

```
    '''Parameters:
    ...Type something.....
    .....finishing statement'''
```

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same problem while accessing any hard drive directory. 
Then I solved it in this way.

```
 import os
 os.startfile("D:\folder_name\file_name") #running shortcut
 os.startfile("F:") #accessing directory
```

[image]

The picture above shows an error and resolved output.

Answer (score 0):

Most previous answers are correct and my answer is very similar to aaronasterling, you could also do 3 single quotations 
s1='''some very long string............'''

Answer (score 0):

The error "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal" occurs when there is an issue with the way a string is defined in the code. The error message indicates that the end of the string was reached before the string was closed properly.
Note: make sure that the file paths are properly escaped using the backslash character ()

Answer (score 0):

use \ in the end of window path, and it will work just fine, as shown below

```
basePath = r'C:\Users\asaini2\OneDrive - Discover\arpan\Principal Data Science\git-project-config\\'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this message with no string in sight (in IDLE windows python3.8):

oops there was a spurious extra quote mark way back in the code
which was causing the pr0blem to show up in what looked like unquoted text