# python: how to set a string equal quotes?

Tags: python

i have quotes inside a string like this

```
string1="blah blah blah "  some'  thi'ng "  end of string "
```

how do i make sure the quotes are included in there?

please note i have both doubel and single quotes in there

Comment: Why asking (pretty much the same thing) twice ( [python: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561691/python-syntaxerror-eol-while-scanning-string-literal) )?

Comment: @Bertrand Marron: They seem like very distinct (albeit very basic) questions to me, one dealing with a string that runs on for multiple lines, the other on how to escape multiple quote forms in a single string.  The answer may be the same, but for different reasons.

Comment: @Nick T: The OP posted this question a couple minutes after posting the other one. Probably after realizing what his mistake was. It would have been a better idea to edit the other question and not post another one. Plus, if you take a look at his user profile, you'll see that he's been asking questions every ten minutes about **very** similar topics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Triple quotes are harder to break.

```
string1="""blah blah blah "  some'  thi'ng "  end of string """
```

Comment: +1 although apparently SO's syntax highlighter has just broken it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\"` to make quotes not break quotes.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to go through the whole string putting a backslash before every offending quote, i'd enclose the string in triple quotes.  this is especially good for a string that will span several lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\"` for using double quotes within double quoted string.

```
string1 = "blah blah blah \"  some'  thi'ng \"  end of string "
```

OR you can use `'` single quotes for declaring string:

```
string1 = 'blah blah blah \"  some'  thi'ng \"  end of string '
```

OR you can use `"""` triple quotes for string declaration:

```
string1 = """blah blah blah \"  some'  thi'ng \"  end of string """
```

Refer article about [String Literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) for getting complete list of `escape sequences`