# Python error while reading a file EOL

Tags: python, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561691/python-syntaxerror-eol-while-scanning-string-literal)

I sometime get this error when reading a text file

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

EOL means "End Of Line"

You forgot to close quotation marks of the type "stuff" or 'stuff'

like

```
>>> print "hello
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "hello
               ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> print "hello"
hello
```

The caret points to where the problem is