# Convert python string representation with '\n' to real python list

Tags: python, string, list, string-literals

This code gives me an error message - obviously because of the `\n` in the string-list.
Error Message: `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

```
import ast
string = "['Text1', 'Long text\nwith new line...']"
print(ast.literal_eval(string))
```

Anyone ever dealt with that?

Comment: See [python: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561691/python-syntaxerror-eol-while-scanning-string-literal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use raw string literals:

```
string = r"['Text1', 'Long text\nwith new line...']"
print(ast.literal_eval(string)[1])
```

Or manually escape `\`:

```
string = "['Text1', 'Long text\\nwith new line...']"
print(ast.literal_eval(string)[1])
```