# How do I write a bash script in python code

Tags: python, bash

in order to get the version of an app from AndroidManifest.xml  I want to execute this bash command :

> /Users/{PATH-TO-SDK}/28.0.3/aapt dump
>   badging com.squareup.cash.apk | sed -n
>   "s/.*versionName='([^']*).*/\1/p"

I'm trying to embed it in a python script while using os :

```
import os

bashcommand = " /Users/{PATH-TO-SDK}/28.0.3/aapt dump badging 
com.squareup.cash.apk | sed -n "s/.*versionName='\([^']*\).*/\1/p" "
os.system(bashcommand)
```

But I have this error :

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

How can I solve this ?

Comment: The completely trivial fix is to use single quotes instead of double around the `sed` script. Maybe switch to a `r"raw string"` for the command line to avoid having Python do ... *things* ... with your backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest quotes; but really, I would suggest you to run as little code as possible in a subprocess, and do the cleanup in Python instead of in `sed`.

On reasonably recent Python, you should use `subprocess.run()` in preference over `subprocess.Popen()` and definitely avoid `os.system()` which doesn't allow you to capture its output at all.

`subprocess` allows you to pass in a shell command with `shell=True` (but you have to use correct quoting, of course) but if you can replace the `sed` call, there is no reason to want a shell, which makes the whole thing a lot simpler to understand and manage, and reduces the overhead significantly. Splitting the command line into an array yourself is a small price to pay. (Or use `shlex.split()` if you really can't be bothered.)

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

result = run([
         '/Users/{PATH-TO-SDK}/28.0.3/aapt',
         'dump', 'badging', 'com.squareup.cash.apk'],
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, check=True,
    universal_newlines=True)
version = result.stdout.split("versionName='")[1].split("'")[0]
```

Comment: For (much!) more detail, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you

Comment: Hi @triplee, can you explain me this error please :
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manifestinfos.py", line 64, in <module>
    universal_newlines=True)
  File "/Users/***/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 468, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Users/***/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt', 'dump', 'badging', 'com.squareup.cash.apk']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: The command didn't complete successfully. If you know this is safe to ignore, take out the `check=True`; but you really need to check the command's documentation to understand why it's failing.

Comment: Hi @triplee, I adapted your code to loop for several applications but I don't understand the error.
    def getVersionName(pkg_name):
    result = run([
             '../aapt',
             'dump', 'badging', pkg_name],
        stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True)
    version = result.stdout.split("versionName='")[1].split("'")[0]

It only works for the first app when I execute functions 
getVersionName("com.ubercab.apk")
# getVersionName("com.bambuna.podcastaddict") 
 I have a IndexError (list index out of range) for other apps do you know why ? Ty

Comment: Maybe post a new question, or ping me in chat.

Comment: How can I contact you by chat ?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187599/room-for-tripleee-and-10485625

Answer (score 0):

Your string has double quotes that end it partway through. Wrap it in triple quotes instead:

```
bashcommand = '''/Users/{PATH-TO-SDK}/28.0.3/aapt dump badging com.squareup.cash.apk | sed -n "s/.*versionName='\([^']*\).*/\1/p"'''
```

Also, I'd suggest not using `os.system`, and instead using `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(bashcommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

**Edit**

For those that would prefer not to use `Popen`, `call` can be used instead:

```
res = subprocess.call(bashcommand, shell=True)
```

Note that using the `shell=True` argument can be a security risk (by opening your program to shell injection attacks), so only do so with sanitized input.

Comment: Don't use `Popen` if you can avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

If you have multi-line statements then wrap in `'''` three quotes.

Read [python: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561691/python-syntaxerror-eol-while-scanning-string-literal)

```
import os

bashcommand = ''' /Users/{PATH-TO-SDK}/28.0.3/aapt dump badging 
com.squareup.cash.apk | sed -n "s/.*versionName='\([^']*\).*/\1/p'''
os.system(bashcommand)
```

Comment: That's not the problem here; the command should apparenlty be all on a single line really.

Comment: @tripleee it gave me the output on my console with no issues.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you ran successfully. The above will attempt to run two commands, the latter of which is `com.squareup.cash.apk`. Do you really have a command with this name installed on your system? What does it do?