# Parsing escape character in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I have

```py
path = "/Users/xx/datasets/yyy/DefinedTS\Training\00000"
```

I just want to replace the '\' escape character with the '/'. 
I have tried:

```
path.replace("/","\")
```

But I got the error : EOL while scanning string literal

I also tried regex, writing my own function, trying to convert to ascii and replacing, but everything seems to reflect the same problem.

EDIT:
I meant I tried

```py
path.replace("\","/")
```

Thanks to UncleZeiv for pointing it out.

Comment: take a look at this, it may help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5141611/5464805. 
Actually "EOL" means "End of Line". Not an expert in python, but it could have something to do with the `\n`, i.e. end of line, which contains a `\\`

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I resolved it using the answer I accepted below :) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems:

- The syntax of your `path.replace` line is incorrect. `\` is an escape character and as such it needs to be escaped by prepending another `\`.
- `path.replace` works the other way around: first the thing you want to substitute, then the thing you want to substitute it with.
- Your string doesn't contain all of the backslashes anymore, because they have been interpreted as ... escape characters. You need to create a "raw" string.

Putting it all together:

```
path = r"/Users/xx/datasets/yyy/DefinedTS\Training\00000"
path = path.replace("\\", "/")
print(path)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. One more thing though:  .replace is not an in-place operation so I will have to do assign it to a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since \ is a special character it needs to be escaped with another \

`path = path.replace("/","\\")`

Answer (score 0):

[Edited]

After seeing UncleZeiv answer, I agree that you need to make it a raw string before replacing it with the backslash. So it should be:

```
path = r"/Users/xx/datasets/yyy/DefinedTS\Training\00000"
path = path.replace("/","\\")
```