# Python Syntax Error EOL while scanning string literal - why it happens and how to fix it?

Tags: python, string, syntax, syntax-error

I wrote this code:

```
def main():
    num_tokens = []
    str_tokens = []
    user_data = input("Insert Delimited Data: ")
    split_data = user_data.split(sep="|")
    for i in split_data:
        if i.strip().isnumeric():
            num_tokens.append(i)
        else:
            str_tokens.append(i)
    print("String Tokens: {}\nNumeric Tokens: {}.format(len(str_tokens), len(num_tokens)))
    return
```

And it says EOL while scanning string literal, what does that mean and why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561691/python-syntaxerror-eol-while-scanning-string-literal)

Comment: Yes, and that was a big mistake, forgetting to type the "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Is a syntax error, because that the last line is malformed.

The closing `"` of the string format is missing.

Change:

```
print("String Tokens: {}\nNumeric Tokens: {}.format(len(str_tokens), len(num_tokens)))
```

To:

```
print("String Tokens: {}\nNumeric Tokens: {}".format(len(str_tokens), len(num_tokens)))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561691/python-syntaxerror-eol-while-scanning-string-literal