# Python: Replace Backslash with Slash

Tags: python, syntax-error, special-characters

I have a path with backslashes like `path = "F:\Downloads\Images\Product\Samples"` but i want to replace *backslash* with *slash*.
I tried `path.replace("\","/")` or `product_image.translate ({ord(c): "/" for c in "\"})` but i get **SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal**.  What is wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561691/python-syntaxerror-eol-while-scanning-string-literal found this now, it is a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

```
path = "F:\Downloads\Images\Product\Samples"
path.replace("\\",r'/')
```

this should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape special characters by \. Try:

```
path.replace("\\","\/")
```