# How to redirect output of python script to bash variable?

Tags: python, bash

When redirecting the output of a python script, when echoing the output it seems to work, but when I actually use it with another object, it breaks and cuts off everything after it.

In this case, we have `VERSION` set to `"nice dude"`

```sh
VERSION=$(python3 -c "print('nice dude')")
```

And printing the variable alone seems to work

```sh
$ echo $VERSION

>>> nice dude
```

But when I implement this value with anything else, Python for example:

```sh
$ python3 -c "print('$VERSION')"

>>>   File "<string>", line 1
>>>     print('nice dude
>>>                     ^
>>> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Or when I print it again with some concatenation:

```sh
$ echo $VERSION hehe

>>>  hehedude
```

I'm not sure what's happening but it seems to be some sort of carriage return when printing an output produced by python `python3.9.1`.

Comment: I couldn't replicate your results

Comment: Even I am not able to reproduce the same.

Comment: There is always a newline at the end of a print, unless you change it explicitly. Use `print("...", end="")`

Comment: here is the [similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561691/python-syntaxerror-eol-while-scanning-string-literal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
VERSION=$(python3 -c "print('nice dude')")
```

the VERSION shell variable will contain a trailing newline, so interpolating it into Python code with `python3 -c "print('$VERSION')"` will result in

```
print('nice dude
')
```

which is not valid Python.

You can either add `, end="")` to the original print or figure out some other way to strip the trailing newline, or use e.g. triple quotes.

Comment: How were you able to replicate the result. Mine is ok. I didn't get any error

Comment: I'm currently on the bus, I didn't even try replicating this since I can just see the issue...

Answer (score 0):

I couln't replicate your result so I tried to look for what might have caused your error.

```py
>> "This is a test
```

Then I got the same error.

It seems your error is that there is un-closed quote at the end.

Look [here](https://www.askpython.com/python/syntax-error-eol-while-scanning-string-literal) for more.

So you're probably forgetting closing an opened quote somewhere at the end.
Here is what possibly might I happened

```sh
VERSION=$(python3 -c "print('nice dude')")
```

```
python3 -c "print('$VERSION)"
  File "<string>", line 1
    print('nice dude)
                    ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: I can see what you're referring to but I actually did include the other quote

`$ python3 -c "print('$VERSION')"`

It prints like that in the error message because of some strange reason, similar to a carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

I added and wrapped the `python` command with `echo` and it worked fine:

```
VERSION=$(echo $(python3 -c "print('nice dude')"))
$> echo $VERSION
nice dude
```