# How to include a double-quote and/or single-quote character in a raw Python string literal?

Tags: python, syntax, rawstring

Consider:

```
>>> r"what"ever"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> r"what\"ever"
'what\\"ever'
```

So how do we get the quote, but not the slash?

And please don't suggest `r'what"ever'`, because then the question just becomes how do we include both types of quotes?

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash)

Comment: In the motivating use case for raw strings (regexes and other cases where something other than Python interprets the backslashes), the backslash is fine, because it will be processed by the regex engine/whatever engine. This doesn't apply to all cases where you might want to use raw strings, but make sure to think about whether it applies to your use case before you try to take the backslashes out.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

If you want to use double quotes in strings but not single quotes, you can just use single quotes as the delimiter instead:

```
r'what"ever'
```

If you need both kinds of quotes in your string, use a triple-quoted string:

```
r"""what"ev'er"""
```

If you want to include both kinds of triple-quoted strings in your string (an extremely unlikely case), you can't do it, and you'll have to use non-raw strings with escapes.

Comment: Excellent. Took me a second to realize I could make triple-quoted strings raw too.

Comment: I like the last paragraph too... this was exactly what I was trying to figure out. The limitations of different quoting styles. I'm comparing Python's `r"raw string"` and C#'s `@"@-quoted string"` and `"""triple quotes"""`

Comment: Python newb here, bit confused, isn't `r'what"ever"` a parse error? Did you mean `r'what"ever'`?

Comment: What's wrong with Python developers? Why didn't they simply implemented an escape system like every other languages do?

Comment: @Jamby They do have an escape system, you just use it with non-raw string (strings without the r in front of them), and it works [like pretty much every other language](https://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: triple quotes! touché

Comment: Just for fun, here's another kind of text you cannot define with a raw string, even using triple quotes: a string starting with a single quote and ending with a double quote (or vice versa). ;-)

Comment: @MiniQuark: `r''''foo"'''` and `r""""foo'"""` work just fine to produce such strings

Answer (score 15):

If you need any type of quoting (single, double, and triple for both) you can "combine"(0) the strings:

```
>>> raw_string_with_quotes = r'double"' r"single'" r'''double triple""" ''' r"""single triple''' """
>>> print raw_string_with_quotes
double"single'double triple""" single triple'''
```

You may also "combine"(0) raw strings with non-raw strings:

```
>>> r'raw_string\n' 'non-raw string\n'
'raw_string\\nnon-raw string\n'
```

---

(0): In fact, the Python parser joins the strings, and it does not create multiple strings. If you add the "+" operator, then multiple strings are created and combined.

Answer (score 10):

Python has more than one way to do strings. The following string syntax would allow you to use double quotes:

```
'''what"ever'''
```

Comment: You missed the *raw* part of the question.

Answer (score 5):

Nevermind, the answer is raw triple-quoted strings:

```
r"""what"ever"""
```

Answer (score 5):

Since I stumbled on this answer, and it greatly helped me, but I found a minor syntactic issue, I felt I should save others possible frustration. The triple quoted string works for this scenario as described, but note that if the " you want in the string occurs at the end of the string itself:

```
somestr = """This is a string with a special need to have a " in it at the end""""
```

You will hit an error at execution because the """" (4) quotes in a row confuses the string reader, as it thinks it has hit the end of the string already and then finds a random " out there. You can validate this by inserting a space into the 4 quotes like so: " """ and it will not have the error.

In this special case you will need to either use:

```
somestr = 'This.....at the end"'
```

or use the method described above of building multiple strings with mixed " and ' and then concatenating them after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

Just to include new Python f String compatible functionality:

```
var_a = 10

f"""This is my quoted variable: "{var_a}". """
```

Comment: f-strings support escaping though, don't they? So you can do `f"foo\"bar"`.

Answer (score -3):

Use:

```
dqote='"'
sqote="'"
```

Use the '+' operator and `dqote` and `squote` variables to get what you need.

If I want `sed -e s/",u'"/",'"/g -e s/^"u'"/"'"/`, you can try the following:

```
dqote='"'
sqote="'"
cmd1="sed -e s/" + dqote + ",u'" + dqote + "/" + dqote + ",'" + dqote + '/g -e s/^"u' + sqote + dqote + '/' + dqote + sqote + dqote + '/'
```