# How to write file in remote windows server from local python script?

Tags: python, remote-server

I am trying to write file in remote windows server using network drive concept but failed to find network location:

```
z = open("\\\\xxxxxxxx\Program Files\abc.txt")
z.write('This is a test\n')
```

Please suggest me alternative options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write string literals in python without having to escape them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703516/how-to-write-string-literals-in-python-without-having-to-escape-them)

Comment: "failed to find network location" How can you tell? Post any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
from os import os.path

filename = 'abc.txt'
# use forward slash instead of back slash
path = '//xxxxxxxx/Program Files/'
outputfile = os.path.join(path, filename)
output = open(outputfile, 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Paramiko` module in python for create SFTP session then you can transfer or create and write files to remote or remote to local