# ignoring backslash character in python

Tags: python, escaping, backslash

If I have:

```
a = "fwd"
b = "\fwd"
```

how can I ignore the `"\"` so something like

```
print(a in b)
```

can evaluate to True?

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore"?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 so b can just be "fwd"

Comment: There is no backslash character in `b`. There is a *form feed character* in `b`, put there by the escape sequence `\f`.

Comment: @KevinR.: then don't use `\` in the string? Not sure what you mean. Or did you want to actually add a backslash? Then double it (to escape it) or use a raw string literal. I.e. `b = '\\fwd'` or `b = r'\fwd'`.

Comment: This should be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703516 but I am out of close votes for today.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don't have `fwd` in `b`. You have `wd`, preceded by [ASCII codepoint 0C, the FORM FEED character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed). That's the value Python puts there when you use a `\f` escape sequence in a regular string literal.

Double the backslash if you want to include a backslash or use a raw string literal:

```
b = '\\fwd'
b = r'\fwd'
```

Now `a in b` works:

```
>>> 'fwd' in '\\fwd'
True
>>> 'fwd' in r'\fwd'
True
```

See the [*String literals* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> Unless an `'r'` or `'R'` prefix is present, escape sequences in strings are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard C. The recognized escape sequences are:
>
> *[...]*
>
> `\f` ASCII Formfeed (FF)

Answer (score 16):

One way of doing it using raw strings:

```
>>> a = "fwd"
>>> b = "\fwd"
>>> a in b
False
>>> a = r"fwd"
>>> b = r"\fwd"
>>> a in b
True
```

The relevant [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

Answer (score 1):

You need to "escape" the backslash, as in:

```
b = '\\fwd'
```

Otherwise, it reads the single backslash + f as an ASCII character (a formfeed).

Here's an example.

```
>>> a='fwd'
>>> b='\fwd'
>>> c='\\fwd'
>>> a in b
False
>>> a in c
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to write a letter `r` to the left of the string as in...

```
str0 = r"\fwd"
```

In **raw** strings, characters are treated literally.

For example, in `r"\n"` is a black-slash followed by a letter `n`.

`r"\n"` does **not** contain a new-line character.

---

`str1 = r"\n"`

| `\` | `n` |
| --- | --- |
| 92 | 110 |

---

You can verify this by printing out the underlying numbers with the **ordinal** function `ord()`.

```
'\\fwd'     [92, 102, 119, 100]
'\\n'       [92, 110]
'\n'        [10]
'\\n'       [92, 110]
```

Test it yourself:

```python
str0 = r"\fwd"
str1 = r"\n"
str2 = "\n"
str3 = "\\n"

tstrs = [str0, str1, str2, str3]

width = max(len(repr(tstr)) for tstr in tstrs)

for tstr in tstrs:
    numbers = list(ord(ch) for ch in tstr)
    print(repr(tstr).ljust(4 + width), numbers)
```