# Can't have \ Python

Tags: python

So i'm still working on my personal assistent code but for some reason i can't have a "\" where i want it. I want my program to take the 2th word i speak and use it to run a program with that name.

```
if words[0] == "atlas":
  print("Succes")
  if words[1] == "launch":
    print("Launch Program")
    p = words[2] + ".exe"
    os.startfile("C:\Gebruikers\Jari\Snelkoppelingen\" + p)
  elif words[1] == "internet" and words[2] == "search":
    url = "https://www.google.be/webhp?hl=nl#hl=nl&q=" + '+'.join(words[3:])
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
  else:
    print("Unknown Command")
else:
  print("Unknown Command")
```

The problem come's here:

```
os.startfile("C:\Gebruikers\Jari\Snelkoppelingen\" + p)
```

I need a "\" at the end of this line but it won't let me.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `\ ` alone is an escape character, you need to write `\\ ` to get the literal backslash.

Comment: [How to print backslash with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095796/how-to-print-backslash-with-python) or [How to write string literals in python without having to escape them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703516/how-to-write-string-literals-in-python-without-having-to-escape-them)

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) is the python documentation on escape sequences.

Comment: It is better to use forward slashes for a [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character, which means "interpret the next character of this string in a special way"; for example, treat `\n` as a newline character.  If you use it to escape `\` itself, that says "treat this as a normal `\` character.

Short answer: use `\\` to represent a single `\` character in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "escape" a `\` character with another `\`. Try:

```
"C:\\Gebruikers\\Jari\\Snelkoppelingen\\"
```