# How can i make a python file run another which is not in same directory?

Tags: r, python-2.7

This is my code...I have tried many solutions given on stackoverflow but i am not able to run another python file which is not in same directory

f.py

```
import os   
print "Start..."
file='"C:\Users\Mohit\Desktop\ML PROJECT\Practical Session on R\Practical 
Session on R\Session II - Regression\run.py"'
os.system('python file ')
print "Done"
```

Output:

```
Fatal error: cannot open file 'file': No such file or directory
```

run.py

```
import os   
print "Start..."
files=r'"C:\Users\Mohit\Desktop\ML PROJECT\Practical Session on R\Practical 
Session on R\Session II - Regression\decisionTree.R"'
os.system('Rscript '+files)
print "Done"
```

**I get the desired result when i run run.py.**

Output:

```
C:\Users\Mohit\Desktop\ML PROJECT\Practical Session on R\Practical Session 
on R\
Session II - Regression>python r.py
Start...

START
elapsed
   0.17

Step 1: Library Inclusion
Step 2: Variable Declaration[1]
[1] "regressionDataSet.csv"

Step 3: Data Loading       RMSD
irNumber
14395 1.167  5364.27   4616.64
15435 2.500 25468.10 475274.00 -
8739  4.039  5921.03   7071.89
11586 0.000 14192.70  75413.00
13765 0.000 17432.40 245147.00 -
10087 3.814  7333.51  26580.70
[1] 16382
[1] "RMSD"          "Area"
[5] "SS"            "ResidueLeng

Step 4: Counting dataset[1] 1638

Step 5: Choose Target Variable[1

Step 6: Choose Inputs Variable[1
"SS"
[5] "ResidueLength" "PairNumber"
[1] 6

Step 7: Select training dataset
th PairNumber  RMSD
14395  5364.27   4616.64   -696.
15435 25468.10 475274.00 -10600.
8739   5921.03   7071.89  -1658.
11586 14192.70  75413.00  -7939.
13765 17432.40 245147.00 -10885.
10087  7333.51  26580.70  -2746.
[1] 8191

Step 8: Select testing dataset
PairNumber  RMSD
10216 20510.40 254178.0 44500.0
2385   9981.42  28499.0 -4789.0
1886  21107.10 192443.0 -4860.0
13684 17765.00  76543.0 -8164.0
10319  6308.91  10287.3 -3370.0
13088  5844.34  11139.7 -1879.7
[1] 8192

Step 9: Model Building ->  decis
ength + PairNumber
n= 8191

node), split, n, deviance, yval
  * denotes terminal node

1) root 8191 23819.88000 2.364
2) Energy< -6161.885 1592  4
  4) ResidueLength< 387.5 74
    8) Energy< -7785.3 262
    9) Energy>=-7785.3 481
  5) ResidueLength>=387.5 84
   10) Energy< -12910.5 173
   11) Energy>=-12910.5 676
     22) ResidueLength< 467.
       44) ResidueLength>=39
       45) ResidueLength< 39
     23) ResidueLength>=467.
3) Energy>=-6161.885 6599 17
  6) SS< 21.5 1584  3795.813
  7) SS>=21.5 5015 13126.850
   14) Energy< -3971.125 163
     28) ResidueLength< 192.
     29) ResidueLength>=192.
       58) ResidueLength< 26
        116) Energy< -4680.5
        117) Energy>=-4680.5
       59) ResidueLength>=26
   15) Energy>=-3971.125 337
     30) Area< 8601.98 1655
       60) Energy< -2933.36
       61) Energy>=-2933.36
     31) Area>=8601.98 1721

Step 10: Prediction using ->  de
13684      10319      13088
3.24618361 0.51722167 3.10727318

Step 11: Extracting Actual[1] 3.

Step 12: Model Evaluation[1] 0.5
[1] 0.25
[1] 1.19
[1] 48.19
elapsed
0.53
null device
      1
       modelName   r    R rm
 elapsed decisionTree 0.5 0.25 1.

  Step 13: Writing to file
  Step 14: Saving the Model -> dec
   Done
 Total Time Taken:  0.53  secDone
```

**But i get the following error when i run it through f.py**

Error:

```
  Start...
  Start...

   START
  elapsed
  0.18

  Step 1: Library Inclusion
  Step 2: Variable Declaration[1] "decisionTree"
  [1] "regressionDataSet.csv"

  Step 3: Data LoadingError in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connec
  Calls: read.csv -> read.table -> file
  In addition: Warning message:
  In file(file, "rt") :
     cannot open file 'regressionDataSet.csv': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an `r` in front of your file path, so that the backslashes `\` don't escape strings where you don't want them to be escaped ([see also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703516/how-to-write-string-literals-in-python-without-having-to-escape-them)).

Secondly `os.system('python file')` will literally execute `python file`, your variable isn't being used.

Also make sure there's no linebreak your file path (just one long line).

```
import os   
print "Start..."

folder = r'C:\Users\Mohit\Desktop\ML PROJECT\Practical Session on R\Practical Session on R\Session II - Regression'
file= r'"{}\run.py"'.format(folder)

os.chdir(folder)
os.system('python '+file)

print "Done"
```

Comment: My original problem is solved...but i have edited the question and stuck in another problem.(Description is provided in the body)

Comment: @MohitKhandelwal use `os.chdir` to change into the python file's directory (see question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810743/how-to-set-the-current-working-directory-in-python). I'm assuming the missing file regressionDataSet.csv and your run.py are in the same folder. I edited my answer.

Comment: please check my this question