# Trying to make a self duplicating file in a specified path

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

**What this does is that it keeps creating a .txt file that keeps duplicating itself in the path that the program is started, here is the code(that works):**

```
import os
import time

file = "1"

while 1 > 0:
   f= open(file + ".txt","a")
   time.sleep(1)
   file += "1"
```

**So what I'm trying to do is that I want to choose a specified path to create and duplicate the (.txt) file instead of the path where the program is started**

**One of the things that I tried:**

```
import os
import time

file = "1"

while 1 > 0:
   f= open(rC:\Users\PC\Documents\ file + ".txt","a")
   time.sleep(1)
   file += "1"
```

**But didn't work.**

**Edit:**

**Last thing I tried was:**

```
import os
import time

file = "1"
path = "r'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\'"

while 1 > 0:
   f= open(path + file + ".txt","a")
   time.sleep(1)
   file += "1"
```

**But unfortunatley gave me [an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW7nk.png) that I havent seen in my whole life:**

Comment: See for a part of your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703516/how-to-write-string-literals-in-python-without-having-to-escape-them

Comment: You need quotes for string `"C:\Users\PC\Documents\"+file+".txt"`

Comment: @xxMrPDDxx I did that but it gives me the error "invalid syntax" at the apostrophe behind the "a" in the same line

Comment: Normally, you would add in the directory you want it to go. What do you mean it didn't work, as the should be an error so theres something going wrong in you specifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there may be other things wrong, at least you should remove excess double quotes around the value you are assigning to `path`, and the final backslash shouldn't be there anyway because you should use `os.path.join()`, - so change to:

```
import os
import time
import os.path

file = "1"
path = r'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents'

while 1 > 0:
   f= open(os.path.join(path, file + ".txt"),"a")
   time.sleep(1)
   file += "1"
```

A happier alternative might be to switch to forward slashes which python handles quite nicely on Windows:

```
path = 'C:/Users/Daniel/Documents'
```

Comment: did that and it gave me an error "EOL while scanning string literal"

Comment: don't think putting quotes around it has solved that problem, just swept it under the carpet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked, I didn't think that I should've imported another library.