# Python: MySQL: Handle Illegal unquoted characters in insert statement

Tags: python, json, mysql-connector

I have MySQL (5.6.10) table with two columns A: varchar(255), B: text

When I run the following:

```
from mysql import connector as sqlserver

Database = sqlserver.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd, db=db)
Database.autocommit = True
Cursor = Database.cursor()

Cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Table (A, B) VALUES (%s, %s)',
               tuple(['This_is_a_test', '\n\nThis is a test\n\n']))
```

Raises the exception:

```
Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash
```

If I do instead:

```
import json

Cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Table (A, B) VALUES (%s, %s)',
               tuple(['This_is_a_test', json.dumps('\n\nThis is a test\n\n')]))
```

Then it is successful, however the value in the table is:

```
'"\n\nThis is a test\n\n"'
```

Instead of:

```
'

This is a test

'
```

I can enter in the value manually to have the correct format, but how should you pass in the string as a variable and have it keep the correct formatting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write string literals in python without having to escape them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703516/how-to-write-string-literals-in-python-without-having-to-escape-them)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57828614/11307485

As stated, add "fr" before the string:

```
from mysql import connector as sqlserver

Database = sqlserver.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd, db=db)
Database.autocommit = True
Cursor = Database.cursor()

Cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Table (A, B) VALUES (%s, %s)',
               tuple(['This_is_a_test', fr'\n\nThis is a test\n\n']))
```

It does not keep the native formatting, but the double quotes from json.dumps() are not present which I can easily work around.

Comment: The `r` is relevant here; the `f` is not helpful, and potentially a security risk.