# Python assign value to a variable that contains ("'{ " and : characters

Tags: python, curl, subprocess

I have the following code:

```
  import subprocess
    cmd = curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "auth_token": "e91a0ffe758c194f0d1d5896eb4daed0", "widget": "79c08a7e70f0253c3da2fab39e7cb89b", "title": "Something", "text": "Some text", "moreinfo": "Subtitle" }' http://collector.superviso.com
    subprocess.call(cmd)
```

I am trying to assign value to a variable which results in syntax error. Here is what happens:

```
>>> cmd = curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "auth_token": "auth_token", "widget": "widget_id", "title": "Something", "text": "Some text", "moreinfo": "Subtitle" }' http://domain.com
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    cmd = curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "auth_token": "auth_token", "widget": "widget_id", "title": "Something", "text": "Some text", "moreinfo": "Subtitle" }' http://domain.com
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE01

The triple quote string does let me assign the value yet subproces not working

```
>>> cmd = """curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "auth_token": "e91a0ffe758c194f0d1d5896eb4daed0", "widget": "329bdbea887ad8e10e4e496f7a60f898", "title": "Something", "items":[{"label": "BOUGHT BREAD FOR", "value": "$999.99"}, {"label": "SOLD WATER FOR", "value": "$9,001.00"}] }' http://collector.superviso.com """
>>> subprocess.call(cmd)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 486, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1201, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

UPDATE02

Thanks to Adam`s post(see above) I was able to sedn the request without assigning any variable:

```
subprocess.call([
    'curl',
    '-X',
    'POST',
    '-H',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    '-d',
    '{ "auth_token": "e91a0ffe758c194f0d1d5896eb4daed0", "widget": "79c08a7e70f0253c3da2fab39e7cb89b", "title": "Something", "text": "Some text", "moreinfo": "Subtitle" }',
    'http://collector.superviso.com'
    ])
```

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't work even without special characters:

```
>>> cmd = curl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'curl' is not defined
```

You're trying to create a string, so you have to use some variant of the string literal syntax:

```
>>> cmd = 'curl'
```

That makes spaces acceptable, and double quotes:

```
>>> cmd = 'curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"'
```

However, you can't nest unescaped single quotes in that. To deal with that, your options are to escape the internal single quotes or to triple-quote the whole string:

```
>>> cmd = 'curl -X post -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \'{ "auth_token"...'

>>> cmd = """curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "auth_token"..."""
```

Comment: +1. and to call `cmd` as a subprocess: `subprocess.check_call(shlex.split(cmd))`

Answer (score 3):

`subprocess.call` also takes a list of arguments instead of a single, flat argument string.  See the [`subprocess` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).  It's much easier to use that than worry about proper quoting.  For example:

```
subprocess.call([
    'curl',
    '-X',
    'POST',
    '-H',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    '-d',
    '{ "auth_token": "e91a0ffe758c194f0d1d5896eb4daed0", "widget": "79c08a7e70f0253c3da2fab39e7cb89b", "title": "Something", "text": "Some text", "moreinfo": "Subtitle" }',
    'http://collector.superviso.com'
    ])
```

Comment: You could also use this as inspiration for another way to create the string literal even if the `subprocess` module didn't - `' '.join(['curl', '-X', ...])`

Comment: I should congratulate Adam for taking attention to this method. It solved the problem!!

Comment: @user2843053: Welcome to StackOverflow.  If this solved your problem, you should [accept it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2):

You want a raw triple double-quoted string r"""blah""".

For more details, see this [How to include a quote in a raw Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630465/how-to-include-a-quote-in-a-raw-python-string)