# How to Hide a Layer using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a form which opens as a popup or iframe (I am not sure), and it has a cross icon which can close the popup.

Code of cross icon:

```
<a onclick="hideLayer('layer_1')" href="javascript:void(0)" class="cls11"></a>
```

I'd like to know how to simulate this in python-selenium. I used `find_element_by_xpath` and `click()`, but it gave `SyntaxError`.

Selenium-code:

```
a = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="xyz"]/a")
a.click()
```

It gives an error window - "invalid syntax in your program".

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO.  Are you able to share the python code you have tried so far, and the exact error traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using two different types of quotes in your `xpath` will correct your `SyntaxError`:

```
a = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xyz"]/a')
a.click()
```

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630465/how-to-include-a-quote-in-a-raw-python-string) for more info on using quotes within strings.