# Python - Escape Quote in Regex within input tag

Tags: python, html, regex

I have an input tag within my python code the looks like this:

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="name" value="value" placeholder="placeholder" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.@#$()+! \'_-]+$">
```

I was able to escape the single quote ' in the required pattern ' but anytime I try to add a double quote ", then it closes the previous double quote (pattern="). I am looking to achieve something like:

```
pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.@#$()+! \'\"_-]+$">
```

where the \" should allow me to escape the quote but clearly that doesn't work like the \' works. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630465/how-to-include-a-quote-in-a-raw-python-string

Comment: Not a duplicate. My question refers to the need to do this within the attribute of an html element. The answer by eph worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
pattern="""^[a-zA-Z0-9.@#$()+! \'\"_-]+$"""
```

You can use `"""` instead.

Comment: Is it possible to use triple quotes in HTML?

Comment: This did not work for me. By adding the additional " it closed off prior " tags in the html.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\x22` for `"` and `\x27` for `'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `r` in front of your pattern:

```
    pattern = r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.@#$()+! \'\"_-]+$"
```

Comment: That would certainly work with Python. The OP wants however to implement the regex pattern as an attribute of the HTML element input. And there are no possibilities for using raw strings ('r').

Comment: Even if it is to be used as an attribute to HTML elememnt input, ('r') can be used.