# Perform diff on two directories by excluding hidden files using Python

Tags: python, bash, diff

I am trying to write a Python script that performs `diff -r` on two directories. I would like to exclude hidden files on the directories.

Here is what I have.

```
source = "/Users/abc/1/"
target = "/Users/abc/2/"
bashCommand = 'diff -x ".*" -r ' + source + ' ' + target
# Below does not work either
# bashCommand = "diff -x '.*' -r " + source + ' ' + target

import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
if output:
    print "Directories do not match: " + output
else:
    print "Directories match"
```

I know that I should use `-x '.*'` to ignore dot files. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630465/how-to-include-a-quote-in-a-raw-python-string) SO post. But it didn't help. How should I write this line?

```
bashCommand = 'diff -x ".*" -r ' + source + ' ' + target
```

Edit 1:
I also tried this and it does not work either

```
pat = "-x \".*\""
bashCommand = "diff " + pat + " -r " + source + " " + target
print bashCommand
```

When I print the output and run the command manually it works as expected. However the Python script is not producing the desired result

```
$python BashCommand.py
diff -x ".*" -r /Users/abc/1/ /Users/abc/2/
Directories do not match: Only in /Users/abc/1/: .a


$diff -x ".*" -r /Users/abc/1/ /Users/abc/2/
$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, single quotes and double quotes mean different things. From [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (') preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.

Whereas for double quotes:

> The special parameters * and @ have special meaning when in double quotes (see Shell Parameter Expansion).

So your `".*"` is getting expanded before being passed `diff`. Try switching the quotes

```
bashCommand = "diff -x '.*' -r " + source + ' ' + target
```

**EDIT**

Popen doesn't normally use a shell to execute your command (unless you pass `shell=True`) so you don't need actually need to escape the pattern at all:

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(['diff', '-x', "'.*'", '-r', 'a', 'b'])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x10c53cb50>
>>> Only in a: .dot

>>> subprocess.Popen(['diff', '-x', '.*', '-r', 'a', 'b'])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x10c53cb10>
```

Comment: It does not work either. When I pass a directory that has dot files, I get the dot files in diff's output.

Comment: Right, sorry - try without the quotes.