# How to run a python script from another python script?

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python script from another as follows, some of the arguments take `quotes (")`,how do I run this command with quotes?

```
cmd =  r"python ./clone.py -u username -rl %s -ra adar.py -d 13346612 -at "Cloning for automation" -m "Pace" -r "Cloning for automation" "%radar
proc = Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

UPDATE#1:I tried the following suggestions but none of them worked

```
  (i)escape the quotes
  (ii)Use multi line quotes
  (iii)Use single quotes as delimiter
```

UPDATE#2:

I tried to run with `shell=TRUE` but the python script hungs

Comment: change `"C....` to `\"C....`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a quote in a raw Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630465/how-to-include-a-quote-in-a-raw-python-string)

Comment: one possible way could be to run command as shell script from python, Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True ). if you can use this, then it might solve your problem.

Comment: @SHAHS - if I run as shell, its just hung, any other pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes ' to delimit your string and double quotes " inside the string to delimit your arguments.

Comment: that didn't work,it throws error `error: unrecognized arguments: for automation" for automation`

Answer (score 0):

Use a [multi-line string](https://www.smallsurething.com/multi-line-strings-in-python/)

Wrap the cmd in 3 single quotes on each side:

i.e.:

```
cmd =  ''' 
python ./clone.py -u username -rl {} -radar.py -d
13346612 -at "Cloning for automation" -m "Pace" -r "Cloning for
automation"  
'''.format(radar)
```

Comment: this didn't work either, the `Popen` fails to run a multi line string

Comment: `    proc = Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` is the exact error