# Python how to get quotes in string like ""It's awesome""

Tags: string, python-2.7

So I wish to print out **"It's awesome"** *with the quotes*

Note not print out **It's awesome**

Thanks a lot

Comment: And where is your Python code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a quote in a raw Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630465/how-to-include-a-quote-in-a-raw-python-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape quotes using `\`

If you are using a print statement. It should look something like this:

```
print("\"It's awesome\"")
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape your strings using `\"` or use single quotes `'`

```
print("\"It's awesome\"")
print('"It\'s awesome"')
```

If you don't wanna escape the quotes for some reason. Note that 34 is the ascii code for `"`

```
print("{}It's awesome{}".format(chr(34), chr(34)))
```

Comment: unfortunate that you have to escape a quote either way :'(

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print("\"It's awesome\"")
"It's awesome"
```

Escape the quotes in the print statement

Answer (score 0):

In addition, to the great answers mentioned here, you can also use a multiline-string without having to usually worry about escaping characters. :) . The way you can write this is by using triple quotes. 
For example, you can try something like:

```
print(r''' "It's awesome" ''')
```