# Getting syntax error while running the code in a particular line in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, syntax-error

It shows me error in this line:

```
name = sel.xpath("//*[@class = "inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words"]/text()").extract_first().split()
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-9-f8d78586cc1a>", line 7
    name = sel.xpath("//*[@class = "inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words"]/text()").extract_first().split()
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You have unescaped double quote characters in a double-quoted string. Either use single quotes for the outer string, or escape the inner double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
name = sel.xpath('//*[@class = "inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words"]/text()1).extract_first().split()
```

---

More generally speaking, you may define strings in python using single quotes or double quotes:

```
str1 = "hi there"
str2 = 'goodbye'
```

However, if you with to define a string with single / double quotes inside, you need to use the other kind outside for string definition:

```
str3 = "he said: `I quote with single quotes`"
str4 = 'she said: "I quote with double quotes"'

print(str3) # yields he said: `I quote with single quotes`
print(str4) # yields she said: "I quote with double quotes"
```

You need to alternate single and double quotes for the string to remain consistent.

Comment: This will change the value of the text itself, which would introduce a problem. Maybe they should use single quotes outside.

Comment: Shir, it worked, but how to identify where we should use single quotes or double quotes?

Comment: I edited the solution to be more informative. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Shir, but the O/P of str1 and str2 were same, what's the difference?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630465/how-to-include-a-quote-in-a-raw-python-string) seem to discuss a similar problem. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Shir thanks a lot, i dont have any qstn right now