# Python 3.4.1 script syntax error, arcpy &

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am used to working in python 2.7 so there was some new things like the print function being different.  So excuse my ignorance.  I am also pretty new to programming.

So here is my script, I keep getting errors that highlight some commas or spaces and saying there is a

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-17: malformed \N character escape
```

Code:

```
import arcpy

print("mosaic to new raster starting!")

env.workspace = "F:\GDAL"
arcpy.env.pyramid = "NONE"
arcpy.env.rasterStatistics = "NONE"
arcpy.env.compression = "JPEG 87"
arcpy.env.tileSize = "256 256"

print("Environment set")

RasterInput = "m_3511401_ne_11_1_20130731.jpg;m_3511401_nw_11_1_20130731.jpg;m_3511401_se_11_1_20130731.jpg;m_3511401_sw_11_1_20130731.jpg;"

print("Input set")

arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(RasterInput,"F:\Pro_Projects\NAIP2013\raster.sde","MosaicFile1","","8_BIT_UNSIGNED","","3","LAST","FIRST")

print("mosaic done!")
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you are not escaping the characters in the file path, particularly the backslash.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380484/using-backslash-in-python-not-to-escape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backslashes (used by you as Windows path separators) signal escape sequences in Python strings. Double the backslashes or use a raw string literal:

```
"F:\\Pro_Projects\\NAIP2013\\raster.sde"
```

or

```
r"F:\Pro_Projects\NAIP2013\raster.sde"
```

Windows also accepts *forward* slashes in paths, avoiding the issue altogether:

```
"F:/Pro_Projects/NAIP2013/raster.sde"
```