# Replace slashes "\" in os.getcwd()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the current working directory and add it to a file path with `os.getcwd`. Because windows uses forward slashes in the directory path, I need to change all of these slashes to back slashes for it to work in python.

What I've tried:

```
import os

old = getcwd()

new = old.replace("\", "/")

file_path = (new + "folder/filename")

print(file_path
```

The above is throwing an error of `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

Comment: "\" is also an escaping symbol. fix: `old.replace("\\", "/")`

Comment: Don't str concat `path`s, use `os.path.join`, or `pathlib.Path.joinpath` for that

Comment: "windows uses forward slashes": ``\`` is a _back_slash. `/` is a forward slash. A good way to remember which is which is to think about which direction the slash would fall if it was a real object.

Comment: I am not sure why this question is closed, but the problem was a misunderstanding in the part of the questioner, and the right answer to the question is to use a modules that know how to work with paths, and the answer given by @Konrad Rudolph  addresses and clarifies both

Comment: Thanks guys. Am new to python here so this is helpful

Comment: Rather than a typo, this should be recognized as a duplicate of [How can I put an actual backslash in a string literal (not use it for an escape sequence)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380484).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Because windows uses forward slashes in the directory path

It doesn’t — it uses *backslashes* (but it also accepts forward slashes).

This works, regardless of operating system:<sup>1</sup>

```
import os

file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'folder', 'filename')
# also works:
# file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'folder/filename')
```

… but the specific error you’re getting is because you’re attempting to use an un-escaped backslash in a Python string. Since backslashes in strings have a special meaning, its usage needs to be escaped: use `"\\"` instead of `"\"`. But as mentioned above, that’s irrelevant here (and 99% of the time when working with paths).

---

<sup>1</sup> A cleaner approach would be via `pathlib`, which uses properly typed objects to encode paths, instead of strings:

```
import pathlib

file_path = pathlib.Path('.').absolute() / 'folder' / 'filename'
```

Comment: Thanks. Green question: would I still have to replace "\" with "/"?  For context, I am using playsound to play sounds in my script and need python to be able to read the file path.

Comment: @patriciajlim No. This should be clear from my answer: this is almost never needed when working with paths, and definitely not here.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I am new to python, so I learned something new :)