# Python path problem: Expected string but found: 'r'

Tags: python, tensorflow, path

i am currently using a config file to train a model in tensorflow. Inside the config file, i need to specify a python path. Since im on windows, my paths obviosly looks like these r"C:\path\path\path. But when tensorflow is using the configfile, i get this error:

`fine_tune_checkpoint: r'C:\path\path\path\ckpt-0': Expected string but found: 'r'`

Anyone has encountered a similar problem?

Comment: `r'string'` is Python code syntax.  You can't use it in other contexts such as config files.

Comment: But if i dont do the r'string', i will get the error:
"'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"

Comment: Before r-strings were a thing, people would just escape backslashes the usual way: Add another backslash before it.

Comment: Like this? \'C:\path\path\path\ckpt-0'

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3380867/843953

Comment: Forward-slashes do work on windows.  Try using `C:/path/path/path/ckpt-0` in the config file.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like it tripped because there was an r written outside of your quotation marks. I'd try to delete that and see if it works, or if the r is in your path, add it within the quotation marks.

Comment: Hi, this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It was an answer for a question that was asked. Why should it be a comment versus an answer?

Comment: It's nice that you ask and I don't mean this in a rude way, but in short, because it lacks quality. There are several reasons: 1) it's very short, answers in most cases should be longer; 2) it's only a guess, neither you or OP validaded that this is in fact the cause; 3) it's wrong. Now none of this is really an issue in itself, it's great that you want to help, but when you are this uncertain, it's better to post the suggestion as a comment. You can always follow it up with an elaborate answer if it turns out correct.