# Can't print out a list of files in a folder using os.listdir ("...") error Python

Tags: python, list, file, printing, directory

I'm trying to get a list of all the files in this folder then print them but I keep getting an error (using python).

import os

files = os.listdir("C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Channel")

Error -  File "C:\Users\Alex\PycharmProjects\First\venv\First.py", line 2
files = os.listdir("C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Channel")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape.

I moved the folder around and changed its name many times but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `\U` followed by eight digits is a way to specify an Unicode character in a string; the backslash serves as an escape character, and is not literally in the string. To include a literal backslash in a string, either escape it with another backslash (`"...\\..."`), or use a raw string (`r"..."`) that does not use backslash as an escape character. Your program breaks before it even tries to access the disk; you cannot fix this however much you move folders around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem above arises because of the character sequence, `\U`. In Python strings, this is an escape sequence used to denote special Unicode characters that wish to be represented in the string and the following characters do not denote a Unicode character causing the above error. I recommend either escape the character, using the `os.path.join` solution to avoid using the character, or to use relative paths in Windows with the forward slash (`/`) to fix the above problem. I have attached a relevant link that might help.

Good luck with your project!

[How can I put an actual backslash in a string literal (not use it for an escape sequence)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380484/how-can-i-put-an-actual-backslash-in-a-string-literal-not-use-it-for-an-escape)