# Could you tell me instead of backslash"\" in python, is any another possibilities available?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

My code is based on Browser Automation with selenium, web scraping. In this concept, we need to give chrome driver path. In windows, the path is with backslash "\". But python does not accept the backslash. Is any other possibility for this? For your reference, I paste my code and error in below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from quotes_page.overall_selenium import Alltags
chrome=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Users\ShanuMadhu\Desktop\python\chromedriver.exe")
chrome.get('http://quotes.toscrape.com')
page=Alltags(chrome)
for pages in page.Paasing_allTag:
    print(pages)
```

**Error**
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: What you're seeing here is the backslash used as an "escape character" - take a look at this post which should contain your solution (you need to "escape" the escape character)- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349439/how-to-escape-characters-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just double up on backslash

I.e

```
chrome=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\ShanuMadhu\\Desktop\\python\\chromedriver.exe")
```