# Python unicodeescape issue

Tags: python, char, hex, unicode-escapes

I worked all day with no result in converting integer to the string of form **"\x.."** at the Python 3.2. When ascii conversion was used or other I get '0x..' or '\\x..', which is not proper for me.
Any bytes or unicode ("\u92") adding operations results with *"SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-2: end of string in escape sequence"*

```
>>>bytes([92])
b'\\'

>>>chr(92) + "x" + str(42)
'\\x42' 

>>> str(hex(66))
'0x42'

>>>ascii(bytes([255])).replace(r"'b\", "")
File "<stdin>", line 1
   ascii(bytes([255])).replace(r"'b\", "")
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> "\x".encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('ascii')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: end of string in escape sequence
```

Comment: Please give an example of the input and output you want.  It's difficult to tell from your post what you're trying to do.  Are you saying you want to go from the number 42 to "\x42"?

Comment: If what you want is `'\x42'`, then that's going to be printed as `'B'`, because they're the same thing.

Comment: It is only a part of mechanism where I have to create strings representing signs I believe that below code is a solution.
    my_data = str("0a") # example
    (chr(92) + "x" + my_data).encode("utf8").decode('unicode-escape')

Answer (score 2):

Oy vey...

```
>>> b'\\x42'.decode('unicode-escape')
'B'
```

Comment: Thabk you. I believe that it is what I was looking for.

Comment: +1 for your mind-reading abilities, they're better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time reading the question, but I believe this is what you were trying to do.

```
>>> aString = str('\\') + str(42)
>>> print aString
\42
```

if you need the x after the \

```
>>> aString = str('\\') + 'x' + str(42)
>>> print aString
\x42
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that in `ascii(bytes([255])).replace(r"'b\", "")`, the `\` after `b` escaped the following `"`, which cause the `SyntaxError`.

Try escaping `\` :

```
>>>ascii(bytes([255])).replace(r"'b\\", "")
```

Comment: You posted the same code again.  Did you mean to add another backslash?

Comment: I know but putting double back slash produce some strange results. I think that
(chr(92) + "x" + my_data).encode("utf8").decode('unicode-escape') 
should solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> chr(92)
'\\'
```

The result shows 2 slashes, but the string really contains only one. That's just the way the strings are displayed. If you `print` it you'll see what it really contains.

```
>>> r"'b\"
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Raw strings are not allowed to end with a `\` so that `\` can be used to escape a quote in the middle of the string. Not sure I agree with that aspect of Python's design, but more information can be found at [Why can't Python's raw string literals end with a single backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash)

```
>>> "\x"
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: end of string in escape sequence
```

You started an escape sequence that would identify a character by its hex number, but didn't follow it with a hex number.

Following up on point #1, perhaps this explains your confusion:

```
>>> chr(92) + "x" + str(42)
'\\x42'
>>> print(chr(92) + "x" + str(42))
\x42
```

Comment: Re `r"'b\"`, a raw string can't end with a single backslash because the backslash 'escapes' the `"`, although it's also included in the string, so `r"'b\""` is printed as `'b\"`.

Comment: @MRAB, thanks. Found a corroborating link and added it to the answer.