# how to replace back slash character with empty string in python

Tags: python, replace

I am trying replace a backslash '\' in a string with the following code

```
string = "<P style='TEXT-INDENT'>\B7 </P>"

result = string.replace("\",'')
```

result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
   File "<ipython console>", line 1
     result = string.replace("\",'')
                                     ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Here i don't need the back slashes because actually i am parsing an xml file which has a tag in the above format, so if backslashes are there it is displaying `invalid token` during parsing

Can i know how to replace the backslashes with empty string in python

Answer (score 42, accepted):

We need to specify that we want to replace a string that contains a single backslash. We cannot write that as `"\"`, because the backslash is escaping the intended closing double-quote. We [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/) cannot use a raw string literal for this: `r"\"` does not work.

Instead, we simply [escape the backslash using another backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095796):

```
result = string.replace("\\","")
```

Answer (score 6):

The error is because you did not add a escape character to your `'\'`, you should give `\\` for `backslash (\)`

```
In [147]: foo = "a\c\d" # example string with backslashes

In [148]: foo 
Out[148]: 'a\\c\\d'

In [149]: foo.replace('\\', " ")
Out[149]: 'a c d'

In [150]: foo.replace('\\', "")
Out[150]: 'acd'
```

Comment: Please don't use Python type names like `str` for variables.  It's confusing and can lead to bugs.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, as explained in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html):

> The backslash () character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

So, in order to replace `\` in a string, you need to escape the backslash itself with another backslash, thus:

```
>>> "this is a \ I want to replace".replace("\\", "?")
'this is a ? I want to replace'
```

Comment: Note that the `\ ` sequence in the string literal in the example becomes an actual backslash followed by a space. When Python scans a string literal and finds an unrecognized escape sequence, it leaves the backslash in the string. (Other programming languages might report an error, or silently remove the backslash.)

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re

new_string = re.sub("\\\\", "", old_string)
```

The trick here is that `"\\\\"` is a string literal describing a string containing **two** backslashes (each one is escaped), then the regex engine compiles that into a pattern that will match **one** backslash (doing a separate layer of unescaping).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a solution if `string='abcd\nop.png'`

```
result = string.replace("\\","")
```

This above won't work as it'll give `result='abcd\nop.png'`.

Here if you see `\n` is a newline character. So we have to replace backslah char in raw string(as there '\n' won't be detected)

```
string.encode('unicode_escape')
result = string.replace("\\", "")
#result=abcdnop.png
```

Comment: Someone who expects to "replace a backslash" in that string (which doesn't actually contain one) has a completely different question, driven by a different misconception.

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape '\' with one extra backslash to compare actually with `\`.. So you should use '\'..

See [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html) -  [section 2.4](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) for all the `escape sequences` in Python.. And how you should handle them..

Answer (score -1):

It's August 2020.
Python 3.8.1
Pandas 1.1.0
At this point in time I used both the double \ backslash AND the r.

```
df.replace([r'\\'], [''], regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Cheers.