# operate with python '\' special character in a string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to iterate in a string and find a character on it and delete it.
For example, my string is "HowAre\youDoing" and I want the string "HowAreyouDoing" back (without the character '\'. My Loop is:

```
for c in string:
     if c == '\':
```

The Point is that '\' is a Special character and it doesn´t allow me to do it in this way. Does anybody knows how can I proceed?
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print backslash with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095796/how-to-print-backslash-with-python)

Comment: Just duplicate the backslash: '\\' the first one anulate the special function of the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, as in most programing languages, the backslash character is used to introduce a special character, like `\n` for newline or `\t` for tab (and several more).

If you initialize a string in python with `\y`, it will escape it automatically, since `\y` is not a valid special character and python assumes that you want the actual character `\` which is escaped to `\\`:

```
>>> s = "HowAre\youDoing" 
>>> s
'HowAre\\youDoing'
```

So, to replace it in your case, just do

```
>>> s.replace("\\", "")
'HowAreyouDoing'
```

If you'd like to replace special characters like the aforementioned, you would need to specify the respective special character with an unescaped "\":

```
>>> s = "HowAre\nyouDoing" 
>>> s
'HowAre\nyouDoing'
>>> s.replace("\n", "")
'HowAreyouDoing'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the character

```
for c in string:
     if c == '\\':
```