# Python : Can't read '\\' as a string

Tags: python, string, pandas, character-encoding

I wanted to replace a string : 'li\\oa' by 'ext'
but I get this error

> error: octal escape value \505 outside of range 0-0o377

I know that the problem is: string containing these chracters '\\', so the question is : How can i read these backslashes as a string.

```
df['col']= df['col'].replace(['li\\oa'],['ext'], regex=True)
```

Comment: Nvm, i found the answer, you need to put '\\\\' backslashes in order for python to consider it as '\\'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the two backslashes by adding one "\" for each one  :

```
df['col']= df['col'].replace(['li\\\\oa'],['ext'], regex=True)
```

Comment: yes thank you, i've already did that

Comment: And it has worked?

Comment: If it worked, please mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a string as raw (with an r in front of it) and it will print all its characters:

```
>>> string = r'li\\oa'
>>> print string
'li\\oa'
```

[How to print backslash with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095796/how-to-print-backslash-with-python)

Comment: I wanted to replace not print

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with print. 'r' will make it to a raw string.