# Print function and normal string in python

Tags: python, string, repr

I am using text that is stored from the `file.txt` and it used for some analyses. After reading text from that file i seeing difference in printed variable value and actual value stored in that variable

```
file=open("message.txt", "r")
message=file.read()
print(message)
```

Printed output: `'MSH|^~\\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4'`

Above result contains printed value of my message. Now i am comparing printed value with the actual value in the `message`

```
if message == 'MSH|^~\\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4':
        print("match found")
else:
        print("No match found")
```

> Output: No Match found

I tried with str() and repr() methods again it is not returning the correct result

Comment: Try `file.read().rstrip()`

Comment: It appears your actual message contains the quotes as part of the string…!?

Comment: Print the `repr` of the message and literally copy and paste that as the string literal to test against.

Comment: @deceze yes as part of input quotes will come

Comment: So, instead of guessing what string you need to form, `print(repr(message))` and copy and paste that exactly as is into `if message == <paste here>`.

Comment: @cricket_007 i tried file.read().rstrip() but returning same result

Comment: @deceze but using repr it is returning `'MSH|^~\\\\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4'`   adding more back slash compred to input.

Comment: Well, then that's the correct representation of your message.

Comment: @deceze but in my input `'MSH|^~\\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4'`  but in output `'MSH|^~\\\\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4'`

Comment: Yes. Backslashes have a special meaning and need to be escaped. `repr` gives you *the valid representation* of the string.

Comment: @deceze repr is not returning the exact result

Comment: It's the *correct* result. Read https://stackoverflow.com/q/24085680/476.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslash characters in the string literal in your code using `\\\\`.
Also you should strip() the contents of the file as mentioned.

The following works for me:

```
file = open("message.txt", "r")
message = file.read().strip()
print(message)
if message == 'MSH|^~\\\\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4':
        print("match found")
else:
        print("No match found")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.can you explain in detail

Comment: But in your printed value four backslash is there but in my input only two backslash is there

Comment: You need four backslashes in the code so Python interprets the string correctly but only two backslashes in the file. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19095831/1619769

Comment: Any other ways to avoid back slashing