# How can I put \n in a string?

Tags: python, escaping, newline

How can I pass `\n` into the dictionary

```
a = {'A': '\n'}
```

Is there any escape character? It interprets it as newline.

Comment: Backslash is the escape character. Or use a raw string. This has nothing to do with dictionaries, it's just the way you type string literals.

Comment: Are you just asking how to escape a backslash? In that case, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/19095796/11301900.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a single backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095796/how-to-print-a-single-backslash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use raw string:

```
a = {'A': r'\n'}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
a = {'A': '\\n'}
```

or raw string as [@Charnel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996863/charnel) answered:

```
a = {'A': r'\n'}
```