# Unable to read hidden file using open()

Tags: python

```
import os
finalFilePath = "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config"
with open(finalFilePath) as wsfinalfile_document:
            openFinalFile = wsfinalfile_document.read()
            print(openFinalFile)
```

When the code is ran, there is no error but there is no output, however, when I move the `applicaitonHost.config` file to a not hidden directory and rerun the code, it printed the content inside `applicationHost.config`.

Comment: The backslash is an escape character try double \\ or put an r in front of the string like this r"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config"

Comment: Also worth noting that [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) advises the use of `snake_case` rather than `camelCase`.

Comment: It is better to use forward slashes for a [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mace mentioned, you have to escape all the backslashes because when Python seems only one backslash it interprets it as an [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence)
Here is the code you want to use, which has the [backslashes escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19095831/9215267) so that Python sees it has a literal backslash:

```
import os
finalFilePath = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\config\\applicationHost.config"
with open(finalFilePath) as wsfinalfile_document:
    openFinalFile = wsfinalfile_document.read()
    print(openFinalFile)
```

Comment: I have tried adding both the r at the front of the string and also using double backslash but there is still no output given. Any idea where the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

After correcting the backslash problem you still get no output so I have tested your code. I have no inetsrv config so I have tested it on powershell.exe.config, also in a System32 subdirectory. Your code ran ok and produced output.

The only reasons I can come up with for not generating output are:

1-no python adminstrator rights for a System32 subdirectory

2-non existing file

3-the hidden directory you mentioned

4-the file is empty

The first 3 reasons should produce an error/exception if not allowed.

The test program:

```
import os

# finalFilePath = r"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config"

finalFilePaths = [
    r"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.config",
    r"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe - empty.config",
    r"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe - non existing.config",
    r"C:\test\hidden\powershell.exe.config",
    r"C:\test\hidden\powershell.exe - empty.config",
    r"C:\test\hidden\powershell.exe - non existing.config",
    r"C:\test\non hidden\powershell.exe.config",
    r"C:\test\non hidden\powershell.exe - empty.config",
    r"C:\test\non hidden\powershell.exe - non existing.config",
    ]

for finalFilePath in finalFilePaths:

    print(f'START: {finalFilePath}')

    if not os.path.exists(finalFilePath):
        print(f'ERROR: file not found {finalFilePath}')

    try:
        with open(finalFilePath) as wsfinalfile_document:
                    openFinalFile = wsfinalfile_document.read()
                    print(openFinalFile)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'EXCEPTION: {str(e)}')

    print('END -----------------------')
```

Testing shows that only reason 2 generates an exception. The other are allowed. *The only way the test program  generates no output/exception is if the file is empty.*

```
START: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.config
<configuration>
...
</configuration>

END -----------------------
START: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe - empty.config

END -----------------------
START: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe - non existing.config
ERROR: file not found C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe - non existing.config
EXCEPTION: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe - non existing.config'
END -----------------------


START: C:\test\hidden\powershell.exe.config
<configuration>
...
</configuration>

END -----------------------
START: C:\test\hidden\powershell.exe - empty.config

END -----------------------
START: C:\test\hidden\powershell.exe - non existing.config
ERROR: file not found C:\test\hidden\powershell.exe - non existing.config
EXCEPTION: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\test\\hidden\\powershell.exe - non existing.config'
END -----------------------



START: C:\test\non hidden\powershell.exe.config
<configuration>
...
</configuration>

END -----------------------
START: C:\test\non hidden\powershell.exe - empty.config

END -----------------------
START: C:\test\non hidden\powershell.exe - non existing.config
ERROR: file not found C:\test\non hidden\powershell.exe - non existing.config
EXCEPTION: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\test\\non hidden\\powershell.exe - non existing.config'
END -----------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```