# How to get single '\' (backslash) printed by a function?

Tags: python, function, backslash

I am trying to print something with a function in python using Jupyter notebook. As an example, let's say I want a function that prints '\x' where 'x' is the argument of the function.

```
def mu():
    a="\\"
    b="mu_"
    return (a+b)
```

This should give me '\mu_' as the output. But it is giving me '\\mu_' as output. I had tried with single '\' first, but there was an error. I found an answer for that problem here in the stack overflow, which allows to print a single '\' by using the double backslash i.e.'\\' But that was for print() command only, and not inside a function. This doesn't work inside a function. Is there a way to make the above function work as I want and get a single '\' in the output as '\mu_'?

EDIT: This happens with any odd number of backslashes. But when I use even number of backslashes, I get back the same even number of backslashes. For odd number the error is:

```
  File "<ipython-input-25-e1de4609aed4>", line 2
a='\\\'
       ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

For the above error, I defined `a = '\\\'` inside the same function as above.

I hope I could express the issue clearly, if not please let me know in the comments.

P.S.- Please note that this question is not identical to some other questions here. The problem is particularly with the 'return' command used inside a function. I just realized that. If I use print(), it works as I want (which has been asked before in this platform.) but I want to know if it is possible to make it work using function.

Thus the narrowed down version of the problem has to do with the return command.

**EDIT:** It is essential for me to solve the problem using a function as I need to append this '\mu_' in an array. printing it is not enough. See the following code:

```
def ten(n,r):
    tiu = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        index = str(i)
        u = 'u^' + '\mu_' + index
        tiu.append(u)
    return (tiu)
```

In the next cell I type:

```
ten(4,1)
```

which gives the output:

`['u^\\mu_1', 'u^\\mu_2', 'u^\\mu_3', 'u^\\mu_4']`

Now if I use 2 '\' in the function, nothing changes in the output. But if I use 3 '\', I get 4 '\' in the outputs.

Comment: Can you please mention the exact code? I'm not able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: ran your snippet and get - `\mu_`, exactly as expected. what excatly don't woek for you?

Comment: How are you printing it? Try printing it with print()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a single backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095796/how-to-print-a-single-backslash)

Comment: `'\\mu_'` is the representation of the string `\mu_` - all seems correct here. You seem to confusing the two.

Comment: @Shradha the function is exact what I defined in the above. Then I called the function with ```mu()``` in the next line.

Comment: @Craig I don't think so. I am not facing this problem if I try to get \mu_ using print only. But when trying to use it in a function, I am getting the problem

Comment: Now that everyone is getting this done, it feels like, there is a problem with the python version I have installed.

Comment: It is not a problem--it is by design, as chepner explains in his answer. You are confusing the internal representation of a string, which you see inside the python interpreter, with the printed version of a string.

Comment: I think I narrowed the problem down a bit. I am getting what I want if I use print() within the function as well. The problem arises if I try to get the answer using the return command.

Comment: @Craig I am not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to say. Honestly I am not a programmer but a student of physics. So I don't know how the code actually works as I have just began to learn python. If you could explain that would be helpful.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `return`. `print()` the array and you'll see the backslashes show up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When printing a list in python the `repr()` method is called in the background. The string stored is '`\`', it's just represented as '`\\`'.

If you print out every element individually, it will show you the `literal value` as opposed to the `represented value`:

```
print(ten(4, 1)[1])
```

Output:

```
u^\mu_2
```

Comment: okay. I understand the concept. Now I have to find a way to use this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem here. The string you are returning contains only a single backslash; it is only the string *representation* of that string that uses two backslashes. Compare

```
>>> r'\mu_'
'\\mu_'
>>> print(r'\mu_')
\mu_
```

Comment: This works fine within print. But there is a problem particularly when trying to do the same using a function. I need the function as I need to print this for varying number of times.

Comment: What, exactly, is your perceived need for `str.__repr__` to return something else?

Comment: The interactive interpreter is not meant as a user interface for your program; you should never *care* what `str.__repr__` returns.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to pass its charater code to chr

```py
print(chr(92))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
a = r"\"
```

instead of:

```
a = "\\"
```

Comment: I am getting an error like :

```  File "<ipython-input-29-2be180629db3>", line 2
    a = r"\"
            ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal```

Comment: A raw string cannot end with a backslash, because backslashes still escape the kind of quote used to define the literal.