# Pytest checking messages returned by errors

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, f-string

Something about the interaction between pytest, str() and python Error types breaks full error testing where we want to confirm the EXACT TEXT returned by the error.

Example below:

```
def erroring_func(name, required_item_list):
   # skip boring bit. Just throw an error.
   raise KeyError(f'{name} is missing required item(s): {required_item_list')
```

```
def test_erroring_func():
    with pytest.raises(KeyError) as err:
        name = 'This dataframe'
        required_item_list = ['a column']
        _ = erroring_func(name, required_item_list)
    assert str(err.value) == f"{name} is missing required item(s): {required_item_list}"
```

This looks sensible, but will return the error:

`assert '"This dataframe is missing required item(s): [\'lat\']"' == "This dataframe is missing required item(s): ['lat']`

Somehow, `str(err.value)` creates single backslashes in the output that are EXTREMELY difficult to recreate in an f-string ([actually impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095796/how-to-print-a-single-backslash)) or to insert in a string once created.

Comment: so, the problem is `KeyError` has a custom `__str__` and the constructor for `KeyError` is meant to be the missing key, that's why you see it quoted.  the backslashes aren't actually there, it's just the representation of the string starts with a single quote so embedded single quotes would be displayed that way in code.  `KeyError` is probably the wrong exception type as well

Comment: The strings in the assert don't match so the `__str__` method defined for `KeyError` has certainly altered something.  I'm tempted to believe the actual error log that it is the backslashes but it could be something else?  As for why KeyError, this is a custom check to confirm df columns before expensive calculations and thus bringing forward what would later be a key error (and making the error message actually useful).  Could make a custom error class, but am interesting in understanding why the default class plays some poorly with pytest.

Comment: change your assertion to use `'"message"'` as KeyError does -- notice the quoting is *both* types of quotes (the repr of the string you've passed in).  compare `str(KeyError("foo'bar"))` and `str(ValueError("foo'bar"))` and you'll see better what `KeyError`'s `__str__` is doing

Comment: I'd also strongly recommend *against using logic in tests* -- it's obscuring your problem and confusing you: https://testing.googleblog.com/2014/07/testing-on-toilet-dont-put-logic-in.html

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Needed to double wrap text strings in quotes of approriate type and order (yuck).  Google thinkpiece is interesting one, thanks. Overall I disagree because that thinking makes unit tests very hard to maintain, although I can see that a larger organisation with slower changing specs might think that way (ie. if you don't change unit tests, who cares about maintainability).  As per one response to it: https://www.andrewtrumper.com/2014/08/complex-logic-in-unit-tests.html

Comment: This code does not make sense and the problem doesn't make much sense either. The built-in `KeyError` does not have a `value` attribute. Please see [mre].

Comment: Karl, you don't know pytest well enough to comment. `err.value` is standard testing https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/assert.html.   Question has MRE, which you can verify by running the code.   However, the solutions presented are now out of date so I'll post an update later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can completely solve by matching how `KeyError` alters text.  This can be done with an f-string with single quotes and then double quotes `f'"your text {here}"'`

```
assert str(err.value) == f'"{name} is missing required item(s): {required_item_list}"'
```

(With thanks to Anthony Sotile)

Answer (score 0):

An incomplete patch (missing the major value of verbose errors) is to test that a fixed substring exists in the returned error.

```
def test_erroring_func()
    with pytest.raises(KeyError) as err:
        name = 'This dataframe'
        required_item_list = ['a column']
        _ = erroring_func(name, required_item_list)
    assert "is missing required item(s):" in str(err.value)
```

PS. Updating to more modern pytest syntax, a regex match can be defined as a arg in `pytest.raises`

```
def test_erroring_func():
    with pytest.raises(KeyError, match="is missing required item(s):") as err:
        name = 'This dataframe'
        required_item_list = ['a column']
        _ = erroring_func(name, required_item_list)
```