# Why print returns \\, not a escape character \ in Python

Tags: python, string, format, encode

The below code prints the emoji like, this  :

```
print('\U0001F602')
print('{}'.format('\U0001F602'))
```

However, If I use `\` like the below, it prints `\U0001F602`

```
print('\{}'.format('U0001F602'))
```

Why the `print('\{}'.format())` retunrs `\\`, not a **escape** character, which is `\`?

I have been checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095796/how-to-print-a-single-backslash) and searched in Google, but couldn't find the proper answer.

Comment: `'\U0001F602'` is evaluated during compile time and a string literal starting with `\U` has a special meaning for the compiler. `'\{}'.format('U0001F602')` is evaluated during runtime (and should be written with an escaped backslash as `'\\{}'.format('U0001F602')` anyway)

Comment: See [Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539) to solve the problem of turning the actual backslash, followed by capital U etc. into the emoji. As for the *question that was actually asked*, it's simple: `\{` **isn't** a valid escape sequence, and Python handles that by treating the backslash literally. The now-linked duplicate is the best reference I could find for this problem - in more recent versions of Python, you will get such a warning message on this code.

Comment: (Warnings are disabled by default; you would need the `-Wd` flag for Python to see this.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referring to [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), when python sees a backslash in a string literal while compiling the program, it looks to the next character to see how the following characters are to be escaped. In the first case the following character is `U` so python knows its a unicode escape. In the final case, it sees `{`, realizes there is no escape, and just emits the backslash and that `{` character.

In `print('\{}'.format('U0001F602'))` there are two different string literals `'\{}'` and `'U0001F602'`. That the first string will be parsed at runtime with `.format` doesn't make the result a string literal at all - its a composite value.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print('\{}'.format('U0001F602'))
\U0001F602
```

This is because you are giving {} as an argument to .format function and it only fills value inside the curly braces.

ANd it is printing a single \ not double \

Comment: Hi, you mentioned that i"t is printing a single \ not double \". Then why `('\{}'.format('U0001F602')) == ('\\{}'.format('U0001F602'))` returns **True** ?

Comment: You have used '==' operator, that operator checks whether the LHS = RHS , and if yes it returns true, and both return the same thing

Comment: Understand it this way,

Comment: When you use \\ it thinks the first backslash is the begining of an excape sequence and \\ prints a \ while a single \ is treated as a string

Comment: Ok, I got it, Thank you

Comment: Main point with the backslash is that it is an escape character. `"\n"` is not a backslash followed by an "n" but a newline, `"\t"` is a tab and so on. If you want to have the backslash itself in a string you have to escape it: `"\\"`. But why does it work here? Python sees the escape character and checks the next character which is a `{`. Now `\{` isn't a valid escape sequence so Python backtracks and assumes that this backslash shouldn't be part of an escape sequence but a standalone backslash.

Comment: Not escaping the escape character itself might lead to some subtle bugs. Check the result of '\\m' == '\m' vs. '\\n' == '\n'. And check what happens when you do `print('\\')` and what happens when you do `print('\')`.