# Backslash in a string gives an error - Python

Tags: python

I want to add a backslash to a list in Python but it gives an error.

Output:

```
chars = [".", ",", "/", "\"]
                        ^
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 8)
```

Comment: this is an escape character. you can either replace with `"\\"` or `r"\"`

Comment: Also related: [How to print a single backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19095796/2745495)

Comment: @jsofri `r"\"` still won't work.

Comment: If you are only using the list to iterate over / check if characters are in it, you probably don't need a list. A string supports all of those operations, so you can just store the characters in a string `".,/\\"`.

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes allow you to enter characters that are normally used by the code, eg. " and '. To avoid the problem, simply just add another back slash. `"\"` -> `"\\"`

Answer (score 0):

It is giving an error because `\` is an escape character, You can store this using escaping this another escape character

```
chars = [".", ",", "/", "\\"]
```