# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (when trying raw string)

Tags: python

I need to check if a lot of certain directories exist. So I have the root directory like that:

```
directory=r"D:\programmming\python\scraper\data\"
```

and I get error `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal` on that line up there.

I need it to end with `\` because the data that I am reading from only has the name of the folder like "foldername" for example. and I need "D:\programmming\python\scraper\data\foldername" to be able to do that:

```
for row in reader:
    name=row[0]
    if os.path.isdir(f'{directory}{name}'):
        print("esists:" + str(f'{directory}{name}'))
```

I knew there was a question like that but I ask this because the original remained unanswered.

I tried changing the string to rawstring, as well as I tried to do that before
`print("esists:" + str(f'D:\programmming\python\scraper\data\{name}'))` and it didn't work.

Comment: If you are going to concatenate `directory` and `name` in the end you can have `directory = r"D:\programmming\python\scraper\data"` and later: `print(rf"esists:{directory}\{name}')`

Comment: Thank you soooo much good person! that solved my problem! also fuck stack overflow for closing my question for no reason. it's good there are still nice people on here

Comment: For questions that I close, I like to directly help the OP with an applicable answer in a comment. This is still a duplicate if a future programmer happens to find this question.

Comment: but it doesn't make sense cuz it doesn't solve the problem (the link that you send me to which question it was supposed to be a duplicate) I think it would be much better to actually tell the user what they did wrong but okay not my problem how u guys run this site

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095796/how-can-i-print-a-single-backslash) is more helpful for you.

Comment: no no. what you wrote fixed the issue thanks. I meant the link to "answered question"