# Why do backslashes appear twice?

Tags: python, string, escaping, backslash, repr

When I create a string containing backslashes, they get duplicated:

```
>>> my_string = "why\does\it\happen?"
>>> my_string
'why\\does\\it\\happen?'
```

Why?

Comment: If you genuinely have backslashes you want to remove, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618030/how-to-replace-back-slash-character-with-empty-string-in-python

Comment: Also arguably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703

Comment: See [Why does printing a tuple (list, dict...) in Python double the backslashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245234) for the specific issue where the `repr` of the string is used when `print`ing a container type (dict/list/tuple) that contains a string.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

What you are seeing is the *representation* of `my_string` created by its [`__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method. If you print it, you can see that you've actually got single backslashes, just as you intended:

```
>>> print(my_string)
why\does\it\happen?
```

The string below has *three* characters in it, not four:

```
>>> 'a\\b'
'a\\b'
>>> len('a\\b')
3
```

You can get the standard representation of a string (or any other object) with the [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) built-in function:

```
>>> print(repr(my_string))
'why\\does\\it\\happen?'
```

Python represents backslashes in strings as `\\` because the backslash is an escape character - for instance, `\n` represents a newline, and `\t` represents a tab.

This can sometimes get you into trouble:

```
>>> print("this\text\is\not\what\it\seems")
this    ext\is
ot\what\it\seems
```

Because of this, there needs to be a way to tell Python you *really* want the two characters `\n` rather than a newline, and you do that by escaping the backslash itself, with another one:

```
>>> print("this\\text\is\what\you\\need")
this\text\is\what\you\need
```

When Python returns the representation of a string, it plays safe, escaping all backslashes (even if they wouldn't otherwise be part of an escape sequence), and that's what you're seeing. However, the string itself contains only single backslashes.

*More information about Python's string literals can be found at: [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) in the Python documentation.*

Comment: I've tried to keep this answer focussed specifically on the "double backslash" misunderstanding, but it's also useful to know about [raw string literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640).

Comment: Input:  'I am 5' 6'
output: ''I am 5\' 6''

I am trying so hard to find easy ways to achieve this but does not seems so easy. Any advice please?

Comment: It's not practical to answer a different question in comments, but careful reading of https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings might help. Note that in order to unambiguously represent a string literal which contains both single and double quotes, Python is forced to escape at least one of those with a backslash. Note also that as explained above, the representation of a string in e.g. an interactive console is not the same as the content of that string.

Answer (score 15):

As [Zero Piraeus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24085681/908494) explains, using single backslashes like this (outside of [raw string literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640)) is a bad idea.

But there's an additional problem: in the future, it will be an error to use an undefined escape sequence like `\d`, instead of meaning a literal backslash followed by a `d`. So, instead of just getting lucky that your string happened to use `\d` instead of `\t` so it did what you probably wanted, it will definitely not do what you want.

As of 3.6, it causes a `DeprecationWarning`, although most people don't see those. As of 3.12, it causes a `SyntaxWarning`. This will become a `SyntaxError` in some future version, per the docs on [escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#escape-sequences).

```
$ python3.6 -Wall -c 'print("\d")'
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \d
\d
$ python3.12 -c 'print("\d")'
<string>:1: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\d'
\d
```

---

In many other languages, including C, using a backslash that doesn't start an escape sequence means the backslash is ignored.

In a few languages, including Python, a backslash that doesn't start an escape sequence is a literal backslash.

In some languages, to avoid confusion about whether the language is C-like or Python-like, and to avoid the problem with `\Foo` working but `\foo` not working, a backslash that doesn't start an escape sequence is illegal.