# How to have a single backslash in JSON response using jsonify and flask?

Tags: python, json, kendo-ui, flask

I need a JSON HTTP response to be as follows:

`{date: "\/Date(1411084800000)\/"}`

I have a python dict `event` with a property date such that

`event['date'] = "\/Date(1411084800000)\/"`

Now when I return the dict using flask I am passing it through `jsonify`. It is unfortunately escaping the single backslash and adding a double backslash to the JSON. `\\/Date("1411084800000")\\/`. I need to get rid of the double back slash, how should I do this?

**You are wondering why I would ever want to return a crazy result like this?**
Well that is how Kendo Scheduler expects date objects. See http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it actually contains two backslashes, and it's not just Python displaying it that way as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice)?

Comment: @BrenBarn Yes I am sure. I looked at the HTTP response using google chrome developer tools.

Comment: Why do you need even the single backslash?  The web page you linked to doesn't show anything in that format.

Comment: How do you assign the value to `event['date']`? The `"`s here would cause a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @dim sorry that was a typo in the post. The python itself is correct

Comment: @BrenBarn Inspect the network traffic on that website and you will see a JSON response with the format I describe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing an *escaped forward slash*. The JSON standard allows *any* character to be escaped, and the forward slash can be escaped by preceding it with a backward slash. See the [*Strings* section of RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7).

So `\/` is an *just* an escaped representation for the value `/`:

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.loads(r'{"date": "\/Date(1411084800000)\/"}')
{u'date': u'/Date(1411084800000)/'}
```

Note how the `\/` is decoded to `/` in the output. *This escaping is entirely optional*.

Your browser does the same thing; when any compliant JSON value which includes strings containing `\/` sequences is being parsed, the resulting string values containg *just* `/` forward slashes. When the [Kendo JSONP response](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks?callback=jQuery191019433633307926357_1411032090244&_=1411032090245) (which does use `\/` in strings) is received, the browser produces the *exact same result* as a JSONP response with the forward slashes left un-escaped.

Just provide the value in Python with the forward slashes. `json.dumps()` will not escape the forward slash (it doesn't *have* to escape it), and your browser and *any other JSON compliant parser* will produce the exact same value:

```
>>> print json.dumps({'date': '/Date(1411084800000)/'})
{"date": "/Date(1411084800000)/"}
```

Answer (score 0):

While Martijn is absolutely correct, he does include a caveat about the far end being compliant. If it isn't, like JustGiving, then you might find the following a useful starting point:

```
class DateJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, datetime.date):
            javascript_date = int(o.strftime("%s"))*1000
            return r'\/Date({0}+0000)\/'.format(javascript_date)
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

    def encode(self, o):
        encoded = super(DateJSONEncoder, self).encode(o)
        encoded = encoded.replace(r"\\/", r"\/").replace(r")\\/", r")\/")
        return encoded
```