# In Python, how can you write the string String = "\s"?

Tags: python, regex, string, escaping

Why does:

```
B = "The" + "\s"
```

and

```
B = "The" + r"\s"
```

yield:

```
"The\\s"
```

Is it possible to write the above, such that the output string is:

```
"The\s"
```

I have read similar questions on both the issue of backslashes, and their property for escaping, and the interpretation of regex characters in Python.

[How to print backslash with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095796/how-to-print-backslash-with-python)

[Why can't Python's raw string literals end with a single backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash)

Does this mean there is no way to write what I want?

If it is useful, My end goal is to a write a program that adds the regex expression for space (\s) to a string where this such space:

For example, start with:

```
A = "The Cat and Dog"
```

After applying the function, this becomes:

```
B = "The\sCat\sand\sDog"
```

Comment: `B = "The" + "\\s"` ? for the function : `B = s.replace(" ", "\\s")`

Comment: That also gives 'The\\s'

Comment: `B = A.replace(' ', '\s')`, `B = A.replace(' ', '\\s')`, and `B = A.replace(' ', r'\s')` are equivalent, and `B` is the regex you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is related to [Why does printing a tuple (list, dict, etc.) in Python double the backslashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245234)

The representation of the string and what it actually contains can differ.

Observe:

```
>>> B = "The" + "\s"
>>> B
'The\\s'
>>> print B
The\s
```

Furthermore

```
>>> A = "The Cat and Dog"
>>> B = str.replace(A, ' ', '\s')
>>> B
'The\\sCat\\sand\\sDog'
>>> print B
The\sCat\sand\sDog
```

Comment: You forgot the closing parenthesis on `B = str.replace(A, ' ', '\s'`. OTOH, `B = A.replace(' ', '\s')` is more idiomatic, although I'd probably write it as `B = A.replace(' ', '\\s')` or `B = A.replace(' ', r'\s')` to make it explicit that the replacement string contains two chars - a backslash and a `'s'`.

Comment: Oops... I'll correct the closing brace, but yes your replaces are better

Comment: Thank you for your help in highlighting the difference between what you write in the string, and how Python interprets the string. It appears I can do exactly the search I need with this information. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> all unrecognized escape sequences are left in the string unchanged, i.e., the backslash is left in the result

So while `\s` is not a proper escape sequence, Python forgives you your mistake and treats the backslash as if you had properly escaped it as `\\`. But when you then view the string's representation, it shows the backslash properly escaped. That said, the string only contains **one** backslash. It's only the representation that shows it as an escape sequence with two.

Answer (score 1):

You must escape the `"\"`

```
B = "The" + "\\s"

>>> B = "The" + "\\s"
>>> print(B)
The\s
```

See the Escape Sequences part:
[Python 3 - Lexical Analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

Comment: That still yields:
    "The\\s"

Comment: Try it in IDLE you will see.

Comment: I see what you mean... Explicitly using print changes the output, presumably as it reads the string literal?

Comment: @CharlesMorris check the link i added to my answer, it explains the Escape Sequences

Comment: @emKaroly Python 2.0 from over 15 years ago is quite obsolete, I wouldn't link to that.

Comment: As Stefan Pochmann explains, it's _not_ necessary here to escape the backslash, since `\s` isn't a Python string escape sequence (although it _is_ a Python 're' module regex escape sequence). But it is clearer to either escape it or to use a raw string.

Comment: Thanks for the help - it looks like a lack of understanding of string escaping + not realising that A print A will give you different outputs when viewed in Shell vs Standard Output, was the root of my problem. Thanks for info :)