# Regex Python - Backslash

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove tags in text that are identified by a backslash. For example, for the phrase 'Hello \tag world', I'd like to return the phrase 'Hello world'.  I've tried the following but it doesn't get rid of the '\tag'.

```
print re.sub('\\[A-Za-z]+',' ',text)
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Use raw strings for regexes. ``\\`` puts a literal backslash in your regex, but a literal backslash in your regex doesn't match a literal backslash in `text` - it's treated as an escape character by the regex engine. You need the extra layer of escaping that raw strings provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must be:

```
re.sub('\\\\[A-Za-z]+',' ',text)
```

Otherwise, `'\\'` is treated as a regex special escape character.

Comment: While that is a valid option, raw string notation is usually more convenient.

Comment: @user2357112 that's entirely a matter of opinion. This answer is perfectly valid and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582162/backslashes-in-python-regular-expressions) would have been a better duplicate question.