# How to write in the correct way the following array with special characters?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, special-characters

I want to clean the name of a file but ONLY for the special characters not allowed:

```
char_not_supported_by_file_name = ['\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|']        
tmp_file_name= file

for c in char_not_supported_by_file_name:    
    if c in tmp_file_name:    
        tmp_file_name = tmp_file_name.replace(c, '_')
```

I try to write this list, check if the file's name I want to clean up has one of the 9 special characters I don't want and replace it with an underscore, but my IDE says the array is written wrong. How can I write it in the correct way?

Comment: because this `'\'` is not a valid string. It needs to be `'\\'` this. Also you could use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) instead, and replace all occurences of all chars in one command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you precede a quote with a backslash, it will have been escaped. In other words, it will be a character in the string instead of marking the end of the string. You must escape the first backslash with another backslash:

```
char_not_supported_by_file_name = ['\\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|']
```

Also, `replace` will do nothing if it can't find any instances of the character that needs to be replaced, so you can omit the `if` check:

```
for c in char_not_supported_by_file_name:
    tmp_file_name = tmp_file_name.replace(c, '_')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that will make your code more concise, if you're comfortable with regex, would be using regular expressions instead of an array:

```
import re

tmp_file_name = file
tmp_file_name = re.sub(r'[\\/:*?\"<>|]', '_', tmp_file_name)
```

This solves your original problem as well, which is that the backslash in the first element of your array, `'\'`, is escaping the end quote and turning it into a `'` literal instead of closing the quotations around your backslash.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to import modules, this could be done without the loop, using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```py
import re
file_name = "this/is:a*very?bad\\example>of<a|filename"

res = re.sub("[\\\/:*?\"<>|]", "_", file_name)
print(res)
# this_is_a_very_bad_example_of_a_filename
```

***Note*** the `\` backslashes need to be tripled or even quadropled depending on the exact location. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582162/confused-about-backslashes-in-regular-expressions) and its duplicates for more information. The reason is that those backslashes are escaped twice: once by the interpreter and then again by `re`.