# How to exclude special characters "\x" from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

In my input data, it seems when the logger with which the data were collected runs on low power, it introduces some special characters, like "v" or "@".

I loaded the dataset with pandas read_csv(engine='python'). I had to use engine='python' otherwise I got an error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb6 in position 2: invalid start byte
```

I found how to exclude special characters from a pandas dataframe:

```
df.var_a = df.var_a.str.replace('[#,@,&,�,{,v,?]','')
```

This replaces special characters like "@" with "", but I have also this special character in the dataframe "\x" and I can't remove it with the code shown above, I get this error message:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 24-25: truncated \xXX escape
```

How can I remove "\x" from a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Are you going to remove Unicode sequence ?  Use  `\X` that matches any valid Unicode sequence, including line breaks ?  (that is, `\X` instead of `\x`) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confused about backslashes in regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582162/confused-about-backslashes-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: @smci  The issue is not about missing back slash but on the wrong use of regex meta-charactrers.

Comment: Ok @SeaBean but then the Unicode is due to reading in the dataset with the wrong `pd.read_csv(... encoding=...)`. That's also a known duplicate. Can you please find the dupe target and close as duplicate?

Comment: @smci  According to OP's comment, the issue is also not caused by wrong encoding used in read_csv. It is owing to:   the logger with which the data were collected runs on low power it introduces some special characters,

Comment: eetiaro and @SeaBean: that hugely important point is buried in a comment hidden under SeaBean's answer. It needs to be in the question. eetiaro please edit your question to add that missing information (don't put important stuff deep in comments; they don't get seen, searched or indexed, and often get deleted (ephemeral)). If not, any pandas user would take it it was the well-known "read in dataset using wrong encoding".

Answer (score 2):

Note that `\x` is for matching hexadecimal character in format \xYY e.g. \x20.

If you want to remove Unicode sequence that appears as special characters to you, you can use `\X` (capital letter `X` instead of lower case letter `x`), as follows:

```
df.var_a = df.var_a.str.replace(r'\X', '', regex=True)   # capital X instead of lower case x
```

If you want to remove hexadecimal values, you have to specify the specific values, e.g. to remove hex value \x20, you can use:

```
df.var_a = df.var_a.str.replace(r'\x20', '', regex=True)
```

Probably you can't remove the hex values in a range.  You have to specify each value one by one to remove it, though you can try whether removing the Unicode sequence with `\X` can achieve the effect you want.

*Side note to your existing regex:*

Note that you don't need comma `,` to separate the special characters in the regex character class.

Another point to note is that besides symbols in your list of characters to exclude, there is a character that looks like `v` in your list.  Are you sure you want to remove the letter `v` ?  Or that `v` is a special symbol incorrectly displayed here ?

### Edit

If you want to check which elements are not numeric, you can use [`.str.isnumeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) to check it:

```
df['var_a'].loc[~df['var_a'].str.isnumeric()]
```

### Edit2

If you are sure characters other than floating point characters should be removed, you can use the following to remove characters other than `0-9` and `.`:

```
df.var_a = df.var_a.str.replace(r'[^0-9.]', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Basically, I want to convert a column to float. It seems when the logger with which the data were collected runs on low power it introduces some special characters, like "v". I only want to have numbers. Your suggested solution creates no error message, but when I try afterwards to convert the column to float I still get: "
ValueError: could not convert string to float:" and it does not show me which string could not be converted. How could I find the strings that can't be converted?

Comment: @eetiaro  See my edit above for the way to find the non-numeric string entries.

Comment: @eetiaro  See my second edit that helps you clean up non-floating point characters.  To play safe, you can use my first edit to have a look at the non-numeric characters first before you clean them up with the code in 2nd edit.

Comment: @eetiaro  How's going with your non-numeric fields checking ?   Are my 2 edits helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
df.var_a = df.var_a.str.replace(r'\\x', '')
```

Comment: You don't need double slashes with raw-string

Comment: It executes without error message, but when I try afterwards: df.var_a.astype(float) I get this error message ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\x11596558.00'