# Confusion about backslash in regular expression

Tags: python, regex, escaping

I am trying to understand how regular expression was interpreted in the following case

```
import re
pattern = 'word\\\n'
sentence = 'This is a word\n.'
match = re.search(pattern, sentence)
match.group()
```

It successfully matches `'word\n'`.

From my understanding according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582162/confused-about-backslashes-in-regular-expressions), pattern will firstly be interpreted as `'word'+ backslash +'newline'`, and then `re.search` will search for the pattern of above in the sentence. However, `'word\n'` in the sentence shouldn't match the pattern above because `'word\n'` is interpreted as `'word'+'newline'`.

Can anyone please help me understand the nuance?

I have tried to search the results online but couldn't find anything specific to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex pattern is `word\(line break)`, i.e. "word" followed by a backslash followed by a line break. The backslash is used to escape meta characters or start special sequences. A literal line break is not a meta character, and the sequence *backslash + line break* has no special meaning, thus the backslash before it has no meaning. In other words, you can put a backslash before any character you wish; if the character isn't a meta character and the combination of backslash + character has no special meaning like `\n`, then the backslash simply means nothing and is disregarded.

Thus, your regex is equivalent to `word(line break)`, which matches the string `'word\n'`, because it's "word" followed by a line break.

Answer (score 0):

`\` has a special meaning to the Python interpreter *and* to the regex parser.  It sounds like you already understand that:

```
pattern = 'word\\\n'
```

is producing a six-character string, where the last two characters are `\` and a linebreak.  This string is in turn being interpreted as a regex.

Within the context of a regex, `\` can be used to introduce a special character class (e.g. `\d`), but if it's used before a non-alphanumeric character, it serves as an escape.  Since a linebreak is a non-alphanumeric character, `\` + (linebreak) is a valid regex that matches a linebreak character.