# Python - nested __repr__ reverts newline to "\\n"

Tags: python, string, recursion, escaping, repr

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_ = []
    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join(['this','should','all','be','on','separate','lines']) + str([str(list_val) for list_val in self.list_])

myClass = MyClass()
myClass.list_.append(MyClass())
myClass.list_[0].list_.append(MyClass())
print(myClass)
```

I would expect this code to print:

```
this
should
all
be
on
separate
lines[this
should
all
be
on
separate
lines[this
should
all
be
on
separate
lines]]
```

or something similar, but instead it prints

```
this
should
all
be
on
separate
lines["this\nshould\nall\nbe\non\nseparate\nlines['this\\nshould\\nall\\nbe\\non\\nseparate\\nlines[]']"]
```

That is, when I try to convert an object to a string while already inside the `__repr__` method of another object of the same class, it turns a newline into `\n`, and if I nest it further it results in `\\n`, and each time I nest it it adds an additional backslash before the escape sequence.

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice), it seems that the `__repr__` method thinks I actually want the two characters `\` and `n`, but I don't: I want the escape sequence `\n`. Is there any way to override this and force it to interpret it as a newline rather than two separate characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the `repr` of a string converts special characters to escape sequences.  This means if you call `repr` recursively on a string with special characters, backslashes will pile up:

```
>>> print("First line\nSecond line")
First line
Second line
>>> print(repr("First line\nSecond line"))
'First line\nSecond line'
>>> print(repr(repr("First line\nSecond line")))
"'First line\\nSecond line'"
```

You are encountering this because your `__repr__` calls `str` on a list, and the `str` of a list uses `repr` (*not* `str`) on each item in the list:

```
>>> print('First line\nSecond line')
First line
Second line
>>> print(['First line\nSecond line'])
['First line\nSecond line']
```

Note that the `\n` appears here, just like it did for calling `repr` on the string itself in the first example.  That's because lists call `repr` on their contents to display themselves.

So by doing `str([...])`, you are calling `repr` on the contents of your list, which means you're calling `repr` recursively your nested objects, which means backslashes pile up as you saw.

If you want to avoid this, you need to avoid calling repr on the nested objects.  You can do this by manually crafting a string using `join`, similar to what you already did, instead of calling `str` on a list:

```
def __repr__(self):
    innerRepr = '['+'\n'.join(str(list_val) for list_val in self.list_) + ']' if self.list_ else ''
    return '\n'.join(['this','should','all','be','on','separate','lines']) + innerRepr
```

Then your `print(myClass)` gives your desired result.

Comment: Wow, amazing answer -- difficulty level 11.