# Append to a tuple of a array

Tags: python, arrays, replace, tuples

I would like to add a backslash all doublepoints in a tuble that is in a array...

The code I have:

```
def removeDots (input):
    for i in input:
        p = i[2]
        p.replace(":","\:")
        liste = list(i)
        liste.append(p)
        liste = tuple(i)
    return input
```

Example:

```
Before: [('Hello:bye','Hello:bye'),('Bye:Hello','Bye:Hello')]
After: [('Hello:bye','Hello\:bye'),('Bye:Hello','Bye\:Hello')]
```

Comment: Before and after are the same!?! maybe a copy paste error

Comment: please give us a minimal reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I had the same question. Did you forget to change it?

Comment: what's special with cell 9?

Comment: Fixed it... Didn't showed the backslash after i posted it...

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what this piece of code should do.
you return the input... of course it does nothing!

Comment: @Stefano It should just do it for cell 9 and not for every cell... Will fix it...

Comment: so why do you use a loop? and in your after you modified element 1 & 2... not the 9th... sorry but I am still a bit confused

Comment: @Stefano Because it should do it for every tuble but just for cell 2

Comment: ah... 2... sorry but it was a 9 before!

Comment: cell 9 was a copy paste error... sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def removeDots (x):
    p = []
    for i in x:
        p.append((i[0],i[1].replace(":","\\:")))
    return p

x = [('Hello:bye','Hello:bye'),
    ('Bye:Hello','Bye:Hello')]

print x
print removeDots(x)
```

Comment: you will see \ printed twice... this is normal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice

Comment: seems to work! will shortly try it in the productive environment...
Thank you verry much!

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!!!
Sorry for my errors with the example and everything...

Comment: I can't, my score is to low :/ @Stefano

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def remove_dots(data):
    return [tuple(s.replace(":", "\:") for s in row) for row in data]
```

Comment: This outputs: `[('H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\\:', 'b', 'y', 'e'), ('B', 'y', 'e', '\\:', 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o')]` for `remove_dots([('Hello:bye'),('Bye:Hello')])`

Comment: @Lafexlos but that input is incorrect and has been changed in the question. Each element of the input should be a tuple, not just a string.

Comment: Sorry, then. My bad. Didn't notice that.

Comment: Returned erroe `TypeError: an integer is required`

Comment: @AlexHall `def remove_dots(x):
    return [tuple(s.replace(":", "\:") for s in row) for row in x]


resultSiDynamicData = cur.fetchall()
resultSiDynamicDataReturn = remove_dots(resultSiDynamicData)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of what i think you're looking for. You will need to adjust it to suit your case specifically.

```
def removeDots(x):
    p = []
    for i in x:
        p.append((i[0],i[1].replace(":","\\:")))
    return p

x = [('Hello:bye','Hello:bye'),('Bye:Hello','Bye:Hello')]
print removeDots(x)
```

**Remember to escape the backslash!**

Answer (score 0):

```
def removeDots(input):
    res = list()
    for x, y in input:
        res.append((x,y.replace(":","\\:")))
    return res
```